# Searching for a tag that is a synonym should use the master tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, search, tag-synonyms

Currently, the Tagged pages for a tag that is a synonym is completely empty.  There is no indication that tag has been added as a synonym for another master tag.

A tag search for `[csharp]` shows [0 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/csharp).  The Info page also makes the tag look [blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=csharp&sort=info&pagesize=50).

From an end user's perspective, there is a gap here.  What will a new user to the site think if they encounter this?  Will they be able to make the leap and find information listed under `[c#]`?

**Proposal**:  When searching for a tag that is set up as a synonym under the master, replace the tag with its master prior to executing the search and use the notification bar to let the user know that the synonym has been replaced with its master so that the user isn't confused why they ended up at the [c#] Info page instead of [csharp].

Comment: possible duplicate of [Improve the search algorithm to work with tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57536/improve-the-search-algorithm-to-work-with-tag-synonyms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ok, so if

- the question count is 0 for a `/questions/tagged/` route
- it's for a single tag

we test to see if that's a synonym, and if so, redirect to the parent.