# Add more visual clues when we're dealing with tag synonyms

Tags: feature-request, user-interface, tag-synonyms

As a continuation from question [Searching for a tag that is a synonym should use the master tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59697/searching-for-a-tag-that-is-a-synonym-should-use-the-master-tag), I'd like to propose that more visual clues are given when we're dealing with tag synonyms. At the moment, I get an “(s)” at the end of a tag name when adding tags to a question. Though *I* know what it means, it's not definitely clear. After all, you shouldn't [make me think](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321344758). IMHO it should really read “(synonym)”, preferably italicized to stand out from normal tags with a number at the end. Even better, it should also say with which tag it is being replaced.

It gets worse when searching for a specific tag. E.g., when looking for questions tagged `[c-sharp]` on the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), I can see that tag but it's not clear that it's marked as a synonym. What's even worse, when clicking on the tag I'm instantly redirected to the `[c#]` tag, without any clue what's happening. A user might think that something is broken. It would be more clear when the list would provide a visual clue when a tag is a synonym, like `[c-sharp → c#]` and even better, that the resulting page says that we're automatically redirected to another tag, like Wikipedia does for its synonyms (e.g., look for [C'era una volta il West](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%27era_una_volta_il_West) and you're redirected to the article with the English title, along with a small note “Redirected from …”).

Comment: It would also be nice to receive explicit notification of any tag synonym substitutions made when a question is submitted/edited in case we overlook that information when editing the tag field and think we've made a typo.