# Searching for synonyms on the Tags page seems very inconsistent

Tags: bug, tag-synonyms, tag-search

There are a few [similar questions on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57536/improve-the-search-algorithm-to-work-with-tag-synonyms) that deal with tag search results when using the site-wide search, but my concern is **not** with that functionality; it is rather with the search box on the Tags page (i.e. the one labeled "Type to find tags:") for which I did not find a relevant dupe.

There seems to be a bit of inconsistency in the Tags page with regards to how synonyms are treated, and it leads to what I would consider unexpected results, with the side effect being that it may be harder to find some tags then it perhaps should be.

An illustrative example: on Android.SE we have a [boot-loop](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/boot-loop) tag, intended for cases where a phone is rebooting itself repeatedly due to a system crash/error. A secondary tag cropped up that was named "repeating-reboot", so it was turned into a synonym of "boot-loop". Now if I type "reboot", "repeating", or just "boot" into the tags area of a question, I get the master in the autocomplete list. Great.

However, if I type "reboot" into the search on the Tags page, I get this, and no other results:

[image]

...relevant, I suppose, but *we have a better tag* for boot loops which someone unfamiliar with the parlance might miss now. I would have expected the "repeating-reboot" tag to appear, even if it simply links me to the "boot-loop" tag. In fact, this **does** happen if I search for "repeating" or similar:

[image]

So why does it not show in the first search? It's also a partial match to the synonym, just the second half instead of the first. I would expect it to appear in both of these searches, and arguably (in this case) having it as a result for "reboot" is *more* important.

Also of note, if you search for an actual tag (one that is not a synonym of another), the partial matching works how I would expect - in this example, a search for "loop" will correctly return the "boot-loop" tag in the results. The issue only appears to affect synonyms.

Is this intended behavior, or a bug? If it's intended, would it be possible to improve the search on the Tags page when dealing with partial matches of synonyms?

Comment: Just as a note: the same applies to the "wildcarded urls": `http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/*reboot*` just turns up the "reboot" tag (nothing else), while `http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/repeat*` turns up *nothing*. In both cases, I would expect the mentioned synonym to be listed (along).

Comment: It appears that the actual tag search on the Tags page has a problem with finding synonyms. The tag suggestions box when asking a question *does* find [both tags](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kwk7L.jpg).

Comment: [Another copy of this question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1776) was tagged [meta-tag:status-deferred]. See also Anna Lear's comments there.

Comment: Similar non-duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224818