# Existing tag not shown when searching in the list of tags

Tags: bug, user-interface

The tag [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) exists on this site - it is a [synonym](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/scope/synonyms) of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope).

However, when I display the [list of tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name) and I type the name of this tag in the search box, it is not shown. (See the screenshot below.) The two other synonyms of [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) do not behave in this way. (EDIT: As noticed by [Martijn Pieters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224818/existing-tag-not-shown-when-searching-in-the-list-of-tags#comment734079_224818), (where-to-post) and (allowed-topics), which are the other two synonyms, also disappear as soon as the first character after the dash is typed in.)

When I browse the list of tags page by page, the tag [on-topic-definition](/questions/tagged/on-topic-definition) is shown. (At the moment it is on [page 26](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags?page=26&tab=name), when ordered by name.)

---

Maybe it has something with the form of this tag and with the fact that it is a synonym.

When I tried to search for the tag (on-topic) on [meta.unix.SE](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name) it worked fine. (That tag is not a synonym of another tag on that meta.)

On the other hand, when I tried this with the tag (on-topic) on [meta.math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=name), the tag was not shown. But the tag named [on-topic](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic) exists that meta and it is synonym of (allowed-questions).

Another interesting thing is that when I start typing a [new question on meta.math.SE](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and I start typing "on-topic" into the tag field, no tags suggestions are shown until I write the whole phrase *on-topic*. (Usually most popular tags containing the part I have already typed are shown.)

[image]

The following screenshot is from meta.math.SE:

[image]

Comment: As soon as you include a dash plus one more character the other two synonyms also disappear.

Comment: Actually, I cannot reproduce your behaviour here on Meta; `on-topi` shows me the `scope` tag.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's correct. The tag (on-topic-definition) worked ok, when asking a question here. In fact, I found the problem on meta.math.SE. As mentioned in the post, the tag name (on-topic) exists there. The screenshot is from that meta.

Comment: [This has been reported on Mi Yodeya as well.](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1965/autocomplete-tag-synonyms)

Comment: @Laura, [that meta.MY question](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1965) is about autocompletion in questions. This MSO question is about autocompletion in question and also in the tag-search page; and is thus a combination of the meta.MY question linked to above and something akin to [this other one](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1776); and the latter is the same as http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174044.