# Favouriting a Question should increase reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, bookmarks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why not get reputation when your question is marked a favorite by somebody?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8457/why-not-get-reputation-when-your-question-is-marked-a-favorite-by-somebody)

I guess favouriting a question should increase the reputation of the person who asked question. Favouriting does signifies that the question was very useful and would like to remember it under a separate heading, isn't it?

Comment: Newbie info - Downvotes on Meta mean that people don't agree with your viewpoint/proposal and not that it is not useful (like on SO)

Comment: @JohnP then their view should become part of the answer. Downvoting decreases ones ability to contribute further to the site.

Comment: @Brandon thanks for that. I guess yes. I did not know it.

Comment: the word favouriting appears to be misleading. Shouldn't it be changed to bookmark instead?

Comment: Actually, this sites [FAQ has a note about voting here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) that explains how it is different. There are accommodations for this including the automatic filters that limit questions from downvoted users are relaxed. However if you want to continue to participate constructively you also have to have some occasional answers and questions people do agree with.

Comment: *Favouriting does signifies that the question was very useful and would like to remember it under a separate heading, isn't it?* I agree on giving +1 reputation to the asker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I disagree. Sometimes I favorite questions just to keep an eye on it for later perusal. Not because the question itself is interesting, could be for any number of other reasons including but not limited to

1. I flagged something in the question and I want to see what the outcome is
2. Some kind of discussion or argument is going on in the question itself or one of the answers
3. A badly written question isn't getting much attention (I tag them and then edit them when I get home)

I'd say just keep the +1 to indicate usefulness/goodness

Answer (score 2):

No, not necessarily. If you want to show that a question is useful you upvote it. If you want to remember it to come back or get notifications when it changes, you favorite it. It is important that this does NOT give reputation because there are other uses besides thinking a question is good and useful.

As an example, I sometimes favorite *really bad* questions so that I can come back later when I have a few minutes and see if I can edit them to be better questions.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the act of making a question as a favourite should increase reputation. If you want to recognise a question (or one of its answers) then vote it up. And whose reputation should be increased anyway?

At the moment, marking a question as a favourite is the nearest thing we have to bookmarking/tracking a question inside of Stack Exchange itself, and hence favouriting a question doesn't mean the question should get more rep because it might not mean what you think. 
What if I favourate a question because of one (or more) answers that are really good but I'm not impressed with the question itself? 
What if I favourite a question because I think that it (or again, one of the answers) are an example of a really bad idea. and I want to find it again to show someone else later?

Use the voting arrows to give rep. Unambiguous, granular, clear. 
Use favourites to keep track of questions. Never the twain should meet, imho.