# Is there a way to see the number of Questions that I've voted for?

Tags: feature-request, badges, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Electorate, Pundit, etc badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress)

I'm a-gunnin' for the 'electorate' badge :)

Comment: Deleted my answer suggesting to look at your user-page, since you only see the number of **total votes** there.

Answer (score 0):

It might be by design, but I'd say why is it by design? Or more specifically, why is a more detailed view not available under the hood somewhere? Whilst splitting things up on the user profile page might cause clutter, I can't really see a downside in having this information available somewhere even if it's just hidden away from the casual observer.

Comment: The whys are primarily explained in the [duplicate link from Jon B](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/34440#34440).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're *supposed* to know.  Jeff doesn't want people to "be gunnin' for" any specific badge.  I've seen him say (somewhere around here) that a badge is supposed to be a surprise.  The intended reaction of the user when a badge is received is "Oh, cool!  Another badge!", not "Finally!  I've been working on this badge for a long time!"