# Why is there no way to directly check the number of times you have voted or what you have voted on, on the current day?

Tags: discussion, voting, daily-reputation-limit, statistics

I apologize if this happens to be a duplicate (I did not find any). I am aware of the answers in [Is there a way to see the number of Questions that I've voted for?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50733/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-number-of-questions-that-ive-voted-for) but I'm asking from the perspective of checking how much of the daily limit (which is not a secret) on answer votes I have already expended.

Comment: The votes are stripped of identifiers when they are written to the server.  Keeping track calls for one of those "low(er) tech" solutions:  open up Notepad and keep track of your question votes.  You can see on your profile the total number of votes that you have cast that day, and just subtract out the question votes.

Comment: *The votes are stripped of identifiers when they are written to the server.* -- I doubt that. SE corporate knows who voted for what; that's how they are able to detect voter fraud.

Comment: The user profile pages already report the number of votes casted by a user in a day; what the OP is asking is to know how many times he voted for questions, and how many times he voted on answers. If votes were stripped of identifiers, then SE should not be able to know how many times a user voted in a day.