# Electorate Badge, How many question votes have i got?

Tags: discussion, support, badges, electorate-badge

I am pretty sure that I have now done enough voting to earn this badge on stackoverflow, yet I haven't got it.

Is there a way I can find out what my 1000 votes and been placed on e.g questions, answers and commemts etc.

Thanks.

Comment: See Jeff's answer to this related feature request [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too/34440#34440), where he explains why there is no visibility for this badge progress.

Comment: It's best to just forget about certain badges and keep doing what you're doing.  You'll get them eventually.

Comment: Interestingly Electorate is one of the few badges, maybe even the only one, that you could be on SO forever and _not_ get (depending on your voting habits of course).

Answer (score 3):

1. Badges are calculated as a scheduled job rather than immediately, so don't be surprised if there's a delay between when you earn the badge and when you actually get it.
2. No, there is no way to find out where you got the badge aside from your own deductive skills. That's part of the fun!