# How many votes have I made

Tags: support, data-explorer, voting

I saw an electorate badge, for making (I think) 600 votes, of which 25% have to be on questions.  Seeing that made me curious what my numbers are.  Obviously my profile displays number of UpVotes, but I was wondering if there is a way to make a query to display number of votes a user has made, and what number are for questions, comments, etc.

The Users table has an UpVotes field, but that seems to measure how many votes other people have made on you, not how many you have made on other people.

I don't need a fully formed query - just a push in the right direction.  I looked though all the fields in the query builder, but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55017

Comment: Not a duplicate of that because this question is asking about tracking badge progress using a SEDE query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There currently isn't a way to query progress towards the Electorate badge in Data Explorer. Note that the Electorate badge requires that you vote on 600 questions which need to make up 25% or more of your total votes.