# Which of my comments earned the Pundit badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, comment-badges

I found Jeff's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress) quite interesting. He's basically saying that some of the badges are a surprise. I can accept this, and it is a surprise when I earn said badges. But...

Now that I've earned the pundit badge, my curiosity is piqued and I want to know which comments helped me earn it.

I suppose I don't mind being kept in the dark until I got it, but now I need to know.

Is there a way to find this out? If there isn't, I think it would be a beneficial feature. Similar to the [enlightened](/questions/tagged/enlightened) badge, [popular-question](/questions/tagged/popular-question) badge, etc.

Comment: Your curiosity is piqued.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) should be able to find this information for you.

[This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/945/my-top-ranked-comments) lists your top-ranked comments. It won't be exact due to the out-of-date information, but you should be able to use the top items in that list to infer not only which comments probably are at enough score now, but also to navigate to those comments just to double-check.

Comment: That's great.. must say that `data.stackexchange` is a real gold mine!

Comment: wow is that data ever out of date. For me earning the Pundit badge, only one of those results has 10 upvotes, and that one... I can't even find my comment. Hmmm....

Comment: I've upvoted you based on the fact that data.stackexchange is awesome, however it doesn't seem to show the real data.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: it's real data, but it's updated only once per two months (next: 1st of April). That's why it's kind of outdated most of the time.

Comment: @rockin It's not real data, but it still gives a better picture than the alternatives (of which the best is the `comments` filter on the `activity` tab in your profile page). It provides links so that you can clarify whether or not the comment qualified. Also, remember that Pundit changed to 5 upvotes, not 10.

Comment: Why only every second month? :/