# How close am I for the Pundit badge?

Tags: support, badge-progress, comment-badges

I have a simple query about Pundit budge (left 10 comments with score of 5 or more).

How close am I for the Pundit badge?

Comment: Please can anybody tell me. Why this question is down voted?

Comment: First, because it's tagged wrongly. It should be tagged as [tag:support], not [tag:feature-request] (you weren't requesting this feature to be implemented on the whole SE network, right?). Second, if you search more carefully, you can find [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84268/which-of-my-comments-earned-the-pundit-badge) which more or less the same as you ask.

Comment: Oh, 1 more. Because it's **tagged as [tag:feature-request]**, where votes also mean agreement/disagreement to the request.

Comment: **No worries. I will never ask any question here in future. Thanks a lot.**

Comment: Possibly related: http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-end-of-ragequitting/

Comment: @Braj: There is no need to say that. We are here to help, and useful questions are appreciated with upvotes. Questions that lack searching effort will get downvoted. That's just the way it works.

Comment: Yes I got it. I want to delete this post.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296061/229836

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a Data Explorer query ([this one for example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/171478/how-long-until-i-get-the-pundit-badge)). According to it, you have one eligible comment on Stack Overflow.

In addition, by using the following query:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT 
  SUM(Comments.Score) CommentScore, 
  COUNT(Comments.Id) CommentCount
FROM Comments
  INNER JOIN Posts ON Comments.PostId = Posts.Id
WHERE 
  UserId = @UserId
```

You can count the total score of your comments (in this case, 76)

Comment: I stand corrected. :-) I forget about some of the esoteric uses of SEDE.

Comment: @KenWhite - No worries! The Data Explorer is pretty darn cool, but I did mess up my original query (I was counting all the comments). It should be right now!

Comment: Well, at least I'd only left a comment to the question and not an answer. :-) You might want to point out that the total comment vote count is meaningless after Pundit is awarded, though; the information is irrelevant, as comments are second-class citizens and meant to be transitory.

Comment: @KenWhite - Very true, and for the case of Pundit, the total comment vote count is actually very much useless. What matters more is that first query, since that sorts the individual comment scores (so you can see which ones have at least 5 vote)

Comment: @ChrisForrence thanks a lot for this link. Now I have modified the query as per my requirement. Basically I want to know how close I am to `Pundit` Badge?

Comment: @Braj - On Stack Overflow, you have one comment with at least 5 votes, so you're 10% there :)

Comment: So sad...... :(

Comment: @Braj - You're still young on the site though (two months and 4k+ reputation). The badge will come in time, no worries!