# Why is the description on the badges page so sparse?

Tags: discussion, badges

If you go to [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) you can get the full badge descriptions, I see that.  When you push badges on the top banner next to SO or meta or whatever, you get the full list of current badges with checkmark notification if you have earned that badge and a very short description.  If you click on the name for one of the badges, that brings you to a page with who has recently earned that badge and the same very short description of the badge.  For many badges, this description is incomplete and sometimes confusing.  Can we put a more verbose description of how the badge is achieved or at least a link to a page like the above link where there is a more detailed description with the caveats for each badge.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too/34440#34440) in regards to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too):

> Some of the badges are supposed to be
>   surprises, not World of Warcraft style
>   level grinds based on numbers.
>
> I worry that if we provide too many
>   metrics:
>
> - it becomes noise, like a bunch of
>     inscrutable F-16 cockpit gauges -- how
>     are all these numbers useful except
>     for these specific badges?
> - the badge
>     becomes the explicit goal instead of
>     the desired behavior
> - the badges are no
>     longer a pleasant surprise and reward
>     but an expected "level up""

Comment: Thanks, that was a nice read. What led me to ask the question was a slightly different train of thought. I read the sportsmanship badge on the badges page and assumed (wrongly so) that it was for any question. It wasn't until a bit later that I saw it applied to only questions that I have answered and the answer had to have at least 1 vote. Either way I think that badge promotes bad behavior, but that is my opinion and life continues if everyone disagrees with me. For the sportsmanship badge, the only way to earn that is to realize it was there? I can't see accidentally earning it.

Comment: The answer is unrelated to the question. When I receive a notification, I expect to understand, what it is about. Some badges (e.g. Curious) do not make sense without further clarification.