# How can I see my progress for different badges?

Tags: support, badges, badge-progress

I am trying to obtain more badges on Stack Overflow. For example, to gain Archaeologist I need to edit 100 inactive posts but I am not keeping track of the number of posts I've edited. For Deputy I need to raise 80 helpful flags, etc. How can I view all my statistics about the badges, such as how many more edits I need to do, etc. I'm not doing it for badges, but I can spend a bit more effort if I'm close to getting a badge.

Comment: [This answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34440/152859) by Jeff also fit here. I personally agree to "Some of the badges are supposed to be surprises, not World of Warcraft style level grinds based on numbers" so too much statistics will just ruin the fun.

Comment: I would have to agree, I like the fact that a badge can appear though your personal random wanderings through pages.  It means they truly reflect your style of use and personality (well to a degree...I am probably more boring than my badges make out for example :)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The majority of the badges which exist do not have any method of "tracking" your progress built into the site. Simple badges such as Nice Answer/Question which require a number of upvotes can be tracked by simply viewing your list of questions and answers.

- **Custodian, Reviewer, and Steward** can be tracked in the review panel via the progress bar at the top of each review task. You can also hover over the progress bar in order to open a detailed tracking box of that badge and several other badges:

  [image]
- **Strunk & White and Copy Editor** can also be tracked in the review panel (see *Reviewer*).
- **Electorate** can be tracked in the review panel (see *Reviewer*) or you can track it manually by calculating your statistics in the profile page (see *Civic Duty*).
- **Civic Duty** can be tracked in the review panel or on your profile page in the bottom right summary of votes.
- **Research Assistant** can be tracked by visiting any tag wiki. Your progress will appear at the right.
- **Deputy and Marshal** can be tracked on your profile page by viewing your helpful flags count at the end of your stats at the top. This item only appears if you've had at least one flag deemed helpful.
- **Enthusiast and Fanatic** can be tracked on your profile page next to the "visited" stats near the top. There will be a "*n* consecutive days" piece there.
- **Epic, Legendary, Generalist**, and some others can all be tracked on a single page using the [Stinking Badges! Stack App](http://agent86ix.github.com/stackapps/badge/).

Comment: Unsung Hero: [How Unsung Am I?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7521/how-unsung-am-i), Tag-Specific: [How many upvotes do I towards tag-specialist badges?](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/2357/how-many-upvotes-do-i-have-towards-tag-specialist-badges), Generalist: [Generalist Progression](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/141307/generalist-progression-updated). These could all be combined and turned in to a super-query. I elect someone with SQL skills (read: *not it!*)

Comment: @jmac The problem I have with the Data Explorer queries is they're only accurate for the last update. Especially for something like Unsung Hero, which is a time-sensitive badge. Only answers older than 10 days count (which I don't think is even checked in that particular query), so it could really throw users off.

Comment: Ah, I knew about the delay in updating (though it's only a week old at most usually), but I didn't realize the Unsung Hero was time-sensitive. Perhaps the queries should be updated too! There isn't really a good way of figuring it out yourself, save doing [a search for 0 score accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1933347+is%3Aaccepted+score%3A0..0) and [a search for all accepted answers](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1933347+is%3Aaccepted) and taking the ratio.

Comment: **Yearling** can also be tracked on your profile page next to "member for".

Answer (score 7):

With the more recent changes, badge progress can be seen by hovering over the progress bar in the statistics tab on one of the six pages for review (*First Posts*, *Late Answers*, *Close Votes*, *Low Quality Posts*, *Reopen Votes*, and *Suggested Edits*).

HowTo:

1. Open [the review page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/)<sup>1</sup>, and click on one of the six *Recent Reviews* links:

   [image]
2. Click on the *Stats* tab, and hover the mouse cursor over the progress bar (just to the left of the *Stats* tab):

   [image]

The badges include:

- Reviewing (they are also shown in the right-hand panel on the page)

  1. *[Custodian](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399)* (bronze)
  2. *[Reviewer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68258#68258)* (silver)
  3. *[Steward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68258#68258)* (gold)
- Voting (the bronze badges are not shown)

  1. *[Civic Duty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399)* (silver)
  2. *[Electorate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399)* (gold)
- Editing (the silver badge *[Strunk & White](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68258#68258)* does not appear to be ever shown)

  1. *[Copy Editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67399#67399)* (gold)

<sup>[1]</sup> <sub>The *review* link on the top of the page is not present below a reputation of 125, but it works as a URL (for example, `http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review`). Reputation points may be so low that *all* links to the review queues are dimmed out, but the URLs to those also work (for example, `http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/`). In fact, a way to avoid all the mouse action above and go directly to the page with the progress bar is to add `review/suggested-edits/stats` to the site domain name (for example, `http://tor.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats`).</sub>

Answer (score 7):

In the new user interface, you can go to the following path and track most of the badges from here.

User Profile ==> Activity (Tab) ==> Badges ==> Choose Settings icon at the bottom right

You can then see something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

With regard to edits (before you have the edit privilege), you can see the total number of suggested edits in your profile -

[image]

Go to the `activity tab` and select `suggestions`.  They are suggested edits because they need peer review before they are accepted.

---

How many `helpful flags` you have raised should be displayed in your profile -

[image]

---

If you want a bit more statistics regarding how close you are to other badges, you can add and authorize this Stack App - [StinkingBadges](http://agent86ix.github.com/stackapps/badge/)

Comment: He did specifically mention the Archaeologist badge, so that number wouldn't be useful in that case. Also, the number isn't always accurate. There are things that could cause your edit number to increase but not the number that qualifies you for the badge.

Comment: I wrote the badgesjust as examples. I wonder if there is a page that i can see all of my statistics. Thanks.

Comment: helpful flag `xxx` looks you cross the integer limit :P

Comment: @luc - No idea why I was compelled to hide that number actually :P  It was public during the election in any case :P

Comment: Only 3 `X` ... C'mon! Andrew Barber has 4 closely 5 `X` !