# Track Badge Status

Tags: discussion, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see my progress for different badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137959/how-can-i-see-my-progress-for-different-badges)

Is there a way to view your progress for getting badges?  I'd like to know that if I have to do 'x' 30 times that I only need to do it 'y' more times to get the badge.