# Why is badge progress only shown in review?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-progress

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see my progress for different badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137959/how-can-i-see-my-progress-for-different-badges)

In review there is a nice output of badge progress, and with useful tooltips as to what that badge means and how to progress it. Why is this only shown in the review section? It is useful information for nearly all of the badges, and motivating.

Comment: It's explained nicely in the linked possible dupe. See also [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3230/152859) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112102/152859).

Comment: For what it's worth, I do not believe this is a proper dupe: I was asking the reasoning why some badges are shown, and not others. Those linked questions only address why, in general, badges progress is not shown.

Comment: Close enough in my opinion. Anyhow, review has greater importance as it directly help improve the overall site quality so it's more appropriate to give it more attention.

Answer (score 0):

It can be accessed in the **Review Panel**, and it shows up in the progress bar on the top of your review tasks list. You can either view the full details of the badge earned either by maneuvering over the progress bar or by clicking on it. It will open up the details for that specific badge and also for other badges as well.

I hope this helps you... :)

Comment: That is the example I was pointing to, but it seems to only cover review-related badges.

Comment: *[Illustration of how to display the badge progress](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137959/how-can-i-see-my-progress-for-different-badges/175501#175501)*.