# View votes by questions and answers

Tags: discussion, voting

[image]

It'd be nice to have two more categories: `questions` and `answers`. These seem to be obvious categories to filter by though—was there a good reason for excluding them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that there *were* good reasons to exclude them,  [in this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress).

The question asked in that thread isn't actually about question vs. answer votes (it focuses on badge progress), but Jeff's answer is relevant still:

> I worry that if we provide too many metrics:
>
> - it becomes noise, like a bunch of inscrutable F-16 cockpit gauges -- how are all these > numbers useful except for these specific badges?
> - the badge becomes the explicit goal instead of the desired behavior
> - the badges are no longer a pleasant surprise and reward but an expected "level up"