# How can I see how many edits left for Archaeologist badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, edits

For [Archaeologist](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1286/archaeologist) badge, users need

> Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months.

I can see my all [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447156/soner-gonul?tab=activity&sort=revisions) but, Is there any way to see how many edits of mine fits for `Archaeologist` badge?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are [several queries on Data Explorer for this one](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=Archaeologist). I can't vouch for any of them being *accurate* though, but you can have a play and see.

This one has been favourited a few times, so might mean it is accurate:

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69607/what-is-my-archaeologist-badge-progress

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure that query makes sense - wouldn't `p.LastActivityDate` since have been updated, at the very least by the activity of you editing the post?

Comment: fyi your query said I had 136, but I don't have the badge :/

Comment: How come I got a 0 even though I at least earned an Excavator?

Comment: The query you linked is completely wrong. http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119332/edits-qualifying-for-archaeologist-badge-progress is pretty accurate, it gives me 103 rows on a 2-day-old data dump and I just earned the badge.

Comment: The query you have posted says I have edited 101 posts on EL&U.  I don't think it accounts for the editing of one's own posts. :(

Comment: @Stijn That query gives me 107 results. So I guess it's flawed, because I don't have the archaeologist badge.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yeah it is flawed, that's why I said "pretty accurate" :) but for me it was a lot more accurate than the one linked in the answer.

Comment: @Stijn on other queries I get 87, 103, and 107. How do I know if the one saying 87 results is more or less accurate? :^/

Comment: @Mari-LouA perhaps it was more accurate for me and it's less accurate for you. I guess you'll have to wait and see :)

Comment: Either something is accurate or it's not. And if a query says I have 107 edits when clearly I don't, because I haven't been awarded a badge, then it's pretty much far off.

Comment: The first link in this answer points to the main Data Explorer list of user-generated queries related to the Archaeologist badge. If the Favorited one isn't as accurate as it could be then hopefully one of the others is. If that's the case we can update this answer referencing the mor accurate query.

Answer (score 7):

I tried this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/158831/archaeologist-badge-advancement) and it works fine. This should be more accurate than the others. I obtained 5 edits from there.

[image]

Comment: This one gives me about the right count, the one in the accepted answer definitely doesn't work.

Comment: This one gives me 135 on stats.SE (and by its count I've been well over 100 for many months now). I don't think it can be accurate.

Comment: This query is not accurate, it says I have edited 124 posts, but I haven't received any badge on EL&U. Other queries I have tried pull out 107, 101 but one "forked query" (whatever that is) has me at 87 edited posts.

Comment: Perfect +1, I need 25 more edits for stackoverflow

Answer (score 4):

No.

I don't see a need to.

To [quote Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress/34440#34440) answering a similar question:

> Some of the badges are supposed to be surprises, not World of Warcraft
>   style level grinds based on numbers.
>
> I worry that if we provide too many metrics:
>
> - it becomes noise, like a bunch of inscrutable F-16 cockpit gauges --    how are all these numbers useful except for these specific badges?
> - the badge becomes the explicit goal instead of the desired behavior
> - the badges are no longer a pleasant surprise and reward but an    expected "level up"

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate but I couldn't find it.

Comment: But what if I die before I achieve a badge that I was only *ONE* point away from achieving?!? #tragedy

Comment: You'd better hope you respawn without losing too much reputation then @Thorn.

Comment: Maybe I'll reincarnate in one of the latest Zelda games where if you get hurt (or die, for that matter) you show right back up where you were moments before, [Groundhog Day](http://parentpreviews.com/legacy-pics/groundhog_day.jpg)-Style. BTW, your avatar's moniker reminded me...do you know what "dogfood lid" spelled backwards is? ( [point #77](http://www.buzzfeed.com/daves4/77-facts-that-sound-like-huge-lies-but-are-completely-true) ) It's a real philosophical and liturgical eye-opener & ponderable!

Comment: That's certainly a novel way of thinking about it @thorn. I normally get into arguments about whether rotational symmetry could be considered "backwards;" :).