# What does "inactive" mean exactly?

Tags: discussion, badges

Notice carefully the [**Archaeologist badge**](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1286/archaeologist)

```
Edited 100 posts that were inactive for 6 months.
```

in this context what does "inactive" mean?

Comment: Basically any question that has an active date greater than 6 months. You can see the active date on any question on the right column underneath the tags, `asked` date and `viewed` count.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[**JonW’s answer**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161187) led me to
[**this query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/69607/what-is-my-archaeologist-badge-progress).

From here I learned the "activity" is determined by the variable
`Posts.LastActivityDate`. After this I constructed
[**my own query**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/92869/last-activity-date) to determine the Last Activity Date on posts with both Answers and Comments. Possible events to trigger activity are

```
Question post
Question edit
Answer post
Answer edit
Comment post
Comment edit
```

From my tests these are the actual triggers

```
Question post
Question edit
Answer post
Answer edit
```

Comment: It seems like the Community bumps back to the front page may make a post active again too.

Answer (score 5):

The activities the badge is referring are:

- Editing an existing answer
- Editing the question
- Adding a new answer

For example, on [Integration with the RDF module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/227/integration-with-the-rdf-module) the *active* timestamp, which is clickable, takes me to the question itself, which I edited; on [NFS Directories between 2 Servers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56960/nfs-directories-between-2-servers) the same timestamp took me to [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/56960/nfs-directories-between-2-servers/56961#56961), while now it takes me to the question itself, which was edited on 2015.