# Why have I not received the archaeologist badge?

Tags: support, badges

According to this [Data Stack Exchange query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119332/edits-qualifying-for-archaeologist-badge-progress?userid=61654) I have performed more than the 100 edits necessary to receive the [archaeologist badge on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1286/archaeologist). My guess is that the logic for awarding the badge is different than what the query is representing. That being said, since I have edited 107 posts which seem to match the six month criteria why have I not been awarded the badge?

Comment: Wait a little while Indianna Jones. These things needs to process. How long has it been since you reached the required amount of edits ?

Comment: Edits to your own posts probably don't count.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd I actually guffawed at "Wait a little while Indianna Jones." That said the beginning of the month according to the query. I would have expected it to award by now. :)

Comment: @FDinoff that's probably a good observation I'll fork this guy's query and drop my own posts from it. See what my count is at that point.

Comment: @FDinoff I [forked the query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119801/qualifying-for-archaeologist-badge-progress?opt.withExecutionPlan=true&UserId=61654#executionPlan) and I'm at a total of 97 edits. Will report back when I get three more to see if I satisfy the condition.

Comment: @FDinoff that was the issue. #sigh

Comment: May I ask if you've been awarded the badge yet? On your forked query it states I have edited *only* 87 posts while on other queries it says between 103 and 107. So, I'm a little bewildered.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes I was awarded the [archaeologist badge on June 12 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1286/archaeologist?userid=61654).

Comment: Thanks, so your forked query works the best then. Oh well, the badge will come for me next year.

Comment: I did a few edits yesterday, posts along with tag edits but today the forked query  still reports I have done 87. How come?

Comment: @Mari-LouA the data is not in realtime. According to the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/help#faq) the data is currently refreshed Monday around 3 am UTC.

Comment: I have to wait a week before I see my edits appear? In other words any edits I did on Monday *after* 3 am UTC  won't be recorded until next Monday? Sugar... :(

Comment: @Mari-LouA the edits you performed have been recorded it's just that the dataset for Data Explorer is only refreshed once a week. if you did 13 edits prior to next Monday you'd earn the badge before then.

Comment: Thank you, I haven't done 13 edits but I was wondering what had happened to the four or five edits I did on Monday. Thank you very much for being so clear. :)

Comment: Got the badge! (Why is it only *silver*?)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think this badge needs a **lot** more clarification from the devs. The description from the list of all badges simply says:

> **Archaeologist**
>
> - silver; awarded once; same family as Excavator (bronze)
> - Edited 100 posts that were inactive for at least 6 months
> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Source: [Should I have earned an "Excavator" badge for this?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115012/should-i-have-earned-an-excavator-badge-for-this)

That is probably as undescriptive as you can possibly get. The only thing it even outlines is that edits to your *own* posts do not count. But that leaves a user asking:

- [**What does "inactive" mean?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164294)

  <s>This question asks a key question, and got two answers that *somewhat* outline what inactive means, but doesn't really clarify anything at all, nor is any of it verified by devs. Does the inactivity *always* apply to the parent question? Does it mean that the *entire question* has to be inactive for 6 months and *any* edit to the question itself or its answers will then qualify for the badge and reset the last activity date (again for the *entire* question and all answers under it)?</s>

  This turned out to be fairly straight-forward. The entire question doesn't matter, and the system only looks at the revision history for the particular post you edited. So an an example, you could edit an old answer, then edit a second old answer to the same question, *and then* edit the question and all of that activity would count three times assuming that all three posts hadn't been created or edited within the past 180 days. The "last activity" date on the question *is not ever looked at* and is irrelevant.

  Bottom line: as long as the specific post you are editing was not created or edited within the past 180 days, editing it will increase your progress.
- [**Do tag-only edits count?**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126624)

  <s>This question was answered, and the answer was "no." However, there's no verification from any devs. Can we get that verification please?</s>

  No, the system does not look at tag edits when calculating progress - only edits to the title and body will count.
- **Do edits to the same post count multiple times?**

  <s>I haven't found this question yet on Meta. If we're going off the rules of other editing badges, the answer is probably no. Other editing badges only count the first edit to a post towards the badge.</s>

  No, you can only edit a single post once for the badge.

---

The specific query mentioned in the question here is inaccurate in a few ways.

- Most importantly, it doesn't have any exclusion for if you own the post that was edited, so if you've ever edited your own inactive post, that query will count it. Only edits to other users' posts count.
- It could also *decrease* your count inappropriately in a lot of cases, because it looks for your edit to be 180 days after *all other post history*, but post history also includes close and reopen, tag edits, etc which don't actually affect the badge.
- It doesn't lookup the post itself to make sure it is a question or answer. Edits to old tag wikis and excerpts do not count.

Comment: In this case (and only in this case) I think the ambiguity is warranted. Archaeologists dig up a _lot_ of broken pottery and copper coins, without a promise of ever hitting the "jackpot." When it happens, it is usually a surprise.

Comment: Editing of own posts don't seem to count. Here's a fork of the above query which filters a [users own posts out](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/119801/qualifying-for-archaeologist-badge-progress?opt.withExecutionPlan=true&UserId=61654#executionPlan).

Comment: Now that you have the keys to the kingdom, do you feel like updating this post? :-D

Comment: @MartijnPieters Enjoy your simplistic answers that took way too long to get. ;)

Comment: @animuson: thank you, your efforts have been noted! :-)