# Excavator badge after answer and edit

Tags: support, edit-badges

I recently found [an old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645874/merging-some-sorted-lists-with-unknown-order-sequence/17202968) that related to a real-world problem I had encountered. I put together an answer for it, and then edited the question itself to make it a bit more readable.

My question is about the `Excavator` badge.

> Edited first post that was inactive for 6 months

Does the fact that I submitted an answer before I edited the question mean that the question is no longer considered inactive, and thus doesn't qualify for this badge?

If I had done it in the reverse order, would that have made it ineligible for the `Revival`/`Necromancer` badges instead?

Comment: [We don't really know.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Excavator` badge is now showing up on my profile.
It looks like answering the question first *did not* make it ineligible.

Comment: Most badges are not given instantly but rather by a scheduled job running once every hour or two. Just give it time and only if badge isn't given after several hours it might be a bug.