# How to see current count for sportsmanship badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, sportsmanship-badge

Where can I see required votes or counted vote for sportsmanship badge?

Comment: You can't... :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/34440/172011

Comment: Sportsmanship: You cannot track progress, but you can find here http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65821/find-competing-answers-sportsmanship