# See a list of my top voted comments? Or another way to track progress on Pundit?

Tags: discussion, comment-badges

> Pundit  Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more

I saw a discussion question that mentioned Pundit, which that stated that [stackoverflow doesn't want to show progress for each badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-pundit-etc-badge-progress), however, something like top voted comments seems to fit in with the rest of stackoverflows feature set, as well as indirectly provide a method to track progress on this badge. Should there be (or is there already) a list of my top voted comments somewhere?

Comment: Why would top-voted comments fit in with the feature set? What value do you hope to get out of seeing what comments were top-voted?

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are top voted question/answer in different categories all over the site. I would assume (besides badge progress) that it would help in a similar way of top answers, by identifying some of the feedback left in comments that people found useful. I think that often when working with someone to discover a problem, a lot of the most valuable information ends up in comments, however I have no way of knowing which information ended up being useful.

Comment: Comments should *not* contain valuable useful information, at least not information that should be an answer instead. Comments are highly contextual; only should apply to the question or answer to which they are attached. Ranking such comments outside of that context is useless, in my view.

Comment: @MartijnPieters whether they should or not, they do. Often people will add comments to existing answers clarifying, and identifying edge cases. If valuable useful information didnt exist in comments why would they persist?

Comment: Yes, and those are highly contextual. Useless outside of their context. Comparing those to other comments from other contexts is not useful, not to me at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters not comparing, but looking back and identifying where I provided relevant contribution. (Duplicate link solved my problem)