# Anomalous community user activity

Tags: support, community-user, bump

On the meta home page I noticed the [community user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) is listed as doing *something*, but cannot figure out what it is.  There is nothing on the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34394/show-question-answer-vote-totals) or its [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/34394/timeline), but the recent activity is listed with the same timestamp.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The community user has discovered an important secret of life: How to *seem* to be doing something, while actually not doing anything.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6981/why-does-a-question-appear-as-modified-by-the-community-user

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an automatic process that randomly *bumps* questions to give them second chance, by making them appear in the homepage.

As [officially described here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184511/152859), those are the conditions that a question must first meet:

- At least 30 days with no activity
- Having at least one answer scoring 0 and none scoring more than that
- No accepted answer
- Not locked or closed

Then the process will take randomly max 1 per hour from questions where all the above is true, and bump it. This action is not visible anywhere (e.g. no revision) except the fact it re-appears in the site homepage.

Answer (score 9):

The answer is on the community user profile page..

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/-1

> Hi, I'm not really a person.
>
> I'm a background process that helps keep this site clean!
>
> I do things like
>
> - Randomly poke old unanswered questions every hour so they get some
>     attention
> - Own community questions and answers so nobody gets
>     unnecessary reputation from them
> - Own downvotes on spam/evil posts that
>     get permanently deleted
> - Own suggested edits from anonymous users
> - Remove abandoned questions