# How can I see what percentage of my votes were on questions versus answers?

Tags: support, down-votes, up-votes, electorate-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Electorate badge progress, Pundit, etc too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too)

This is probably a duplicate but after 10 minutes of reading (very long) threads on the Electorate badge I wasn't able to find the answer.

I know that on my user page my total up/down votes are shown, but is there any way for me to know how many of those votes were on questions vs answers? Specifically, how close am I to get the Electorate badge?

Comment: Tagged this with 'discussion' but 'support' may have been more appropriate? If so I will change.

Comment: Thanks for fixing for me @Chacha102!

Comment: @ChrisF: Yes, it is a duplicate. See my answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK. It took me 22 minutes of reading. My question is a duplicate of [Electorate, Pundit, etc badge progress](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too)

Jeff Atwood's answer was accepted for that question, and it basically says that you're not meant to know when you'll get the Electorate badge -- it's supposed to be a surprise.

> Some of the badges are supposed to be
>   surprises, not World of Warcraft style
>   level grinds based on numbers.
>
> I worry that if we provide too many
>   metrics:
>
> - it becomes noise, like a bunch of
>     inscrutable F-16 cockpit gauges -- how
>     are all these numbers useful except
>     for these specific badges?
> - the badge
>     becomes the explicit goal instead of
>     the desired behavior
> - the badges are no
>     longer a pleasant surprise and reward
>     but an expected "level up"

Comment: I looked for this (I knew it had been asked before), but couldn't find it, so well done on that score.