# What happened to the link to the duplicate when a question is closed as a duplicate?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, edits, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible to remove the link to duplicate question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50336/possible-to-remove-the-link-to-duplicate-question)

This question:

- [Why can I not use the namespace directive in a C++ `struct`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856563/why-can-i-not-use-the-namespace-directive-in-c-struct)

has been closed as an exact duplicate, but there is no link to the duplicate so we can neither assess whether the closure is valid nor see the explanations in the duplicate question.  It wasn't so long ago that the duplicate links were shown — is there a policy change (and if so, why?), or is it just a glitch?

Comment: what are empty duplicate question message here? why it's not showing?

Comment: @Donotlikenewbuttons — they are an ancient, temporary artifact that no longer occur.  Once upon a time, the duplicate information was simply edited into the heading of the question, and those with edit privileges could change, or remove, that content.  That's no longer the case — possibly as a result of changes triggered because of problems such as this one.

Comment: okay, thank you for the fast answer! Honestly, it's a surprise to see comment of the user who been lastly seen more than 5 years ago,.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at [the post history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/9856563/revisions). The asker himself edited out the duplicate message when he was adding more details. This was probably an accident; he probably started editing before the question was closed, and when he submitted his edit it overwrote Community's edit (the duplicate message) because it was more substantive.

Comment: That possibility hadn't occurred to me!  I've gone and added the duplicate question information to the question (on top of the last edit).  Thanks.

Comment: There was 7 minutes between Community's edit and the OPs. It may not have been an accident :-).