# What is the community's opinion on modifying older-style duplicate closures to the newer style?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, bump, dupehammer

This is not a duplicate of [Editing duplicate banner edited into the text of the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280798/editing-duplicate-banner-edited-into-the-text-of-the-question). The main question there is only if something "special" will happen if someone edits out the automatic text. The answer addresses this question, but it's from an SE employee; I'm asking specifically for the *community's* opinion on this, which may be different from SE's position.

Should users with gold-badge dupehammer privileges modify older-style duplicate closures where the duplicate targets were edited into the question body by the Community user, into the newer form of closure where the list is an automatic box added above the post? There exists an official response [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280798/editing-duplicate-banner-edited-into-the-text-of-the-question), but I noticed a user going around and doing this, so I was wondering if the community's opinion was different from SE's.

Here's an [example revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/32675/revisions) where such a thing was done.

In my opinion, there's no advantage to doing this because:

- There isn't much visual change made to the post, other than some formatting differences and that the heading now says "This question already has an answer here" instead of "Possible Duplicate".
- Those posts are unnecessarily bumped when this action is taken, from both the reopening and the subsequent edit to remove the target list from the post body.
- The original close voters and original closure date is no longer shown in the question's notice; it instead just shows the one user who performed the modification, and makes it seem like a recent unilateral decision rather than a consensus a long time ago.

I can see one potential benefit: normal users can no longer modify the target list, which now requires a user with gold-badge privileges. But there isn't much evidence of this happening on a wider scale, and as the posts are bumped anyway when that happens, that can easily be rolled back as needed.

Should users go around and change all these old-form closures into the new form? What if a user comes across one of those posts, but it's not active in a while? if it's recently active?

What's the community's position on this?

Comment: If my SEDE skills serve me well, we're talking about [6680 questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/922216/possible-duplicates-old-style) here.

Comment: Is there any way we could re-dupe this question using the old-style closure?

Comment: No. Once reopened and reclosed, it will always have the new style. @rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me the benefit of the new banner is that it automatically updates the question title if the title has been edited after closure of the duplicate question.

The new banner also allows editing the list of duplicates, which is also very useful at time.

For most cases though, updating the banner is just cosmetically. However, if I stumble across an old duplicate question, I will edit it just for the sake of consistency.

Editing just one when you come across it won't hurt the community. Editing en-masse without a script written and executed by SE should not be done. Letting SE do the cleanup makes much more sense, but they don't seem to want to put the time and effort in. So I guess it is not important enough.

Comment: The old banner also allows editing the duplicate list.

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: See revision 7 of https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/83664/revisions. Also, one can work around the title edit issue by removing the link title markup, replacing it with the bare URL, and letting the system add the title automatically.

Comment: Changing the title has no use if you can fix it permanently. That of course only an option if you happen to have a gold tag badge.

Comment: And no, you can't edit the list of duplicates: see [this question for example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160904/add-an-open-ended-option-to-the-off-topic-site-list). There is no edit link.

Comment: Also the old title says "possible duplicate" where the community consensus is that it is a duplicate.