# How about a "Grease Monkey God" badge?

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

The purpose of this badge is to recognize those among us who make Grease Monkey scripts to extend the functionality of the SO family sites further than any of us have imagined.

This should be a Gold level badge and by receiving 15 upvotes on a post tagged with greasemonkey.

Take for example this idea:
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8472/script-infinite-scrolling-of-answers

Comment: Edited the post to reflect TheTXI's suggestion on using a tag vs. moderator...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well if you get enough upvotes with the tag "grease-monkey" you can already get one of the automatic tag badges.

I think that's better than trying to add a new class of badge which would be moderator awarded (something we don't really have at this point).

Comment: Didn't think about that...  Good call...

Comment: I used to tag my contributions as "greasemonkey," but *somebody* came by and re-tagged them :)

Comment: Just give me the check mark :(. Stupid rep limits!

Comment: OK....  I'll give you the check-mark....

Comment: ...You know, you're not supposed to be *asking* for checkmarks, Mr. Rep Farmer.

Answer (score 1):

Just call it "The Sampson". =)

Comment: I think there are a couple other folks who would get close to qualifying for this...  But the name is rather catchy...

Answer (score 1):

I will vote in favor of this if it is modified to recognize an entire range of badges for tangentially-relevant and completely subjective things.  For example, TheTXI deserves a real `OMG PONIES!` badge.  I want one for my beautiful Super Mario castle of `kbd` tags.  **He Who Shall Not Be Named** should get one for troll-hunting.  I could go on and on.

Comment: TROLL HUNTER ++

Answer (score -2):

As a monkey god, just write a book about all the great things you've done and disseminate it widely. Be sure to include large codices on how you prefer to be worshiped and revered for all your super-humanness. Once you've converted Jeff Atwood et al. you should be able to get a badge.

Answer (score -2):

I've heard rumors of a "secret" badge awarded for users that make an important contribution the site implementation.  It's handed out for things like reporting security flaws or providing a patch for the mark-down code.  Perhaps enough grease-monkey work would merit it as well (if it exists).

Comment: That's the mythical Hacker badge: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/no-we-have-not-forgotten-about-the-hacker-badge

Comment: I want this secrent badge.