# Reward users when their feature requests are implemented

Tags: discussion, meta, feature-request-process

I would assume that the suggestions relayed by users of the [SOFU](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420) sites to The Company which are ultimately implemented are considered, at least by [Jeff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeff_Atwood), [Joel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky), et al as good additions to the sites in general.   I wonder if it would be appropriate that these interested users be rewarded for this behavior.

I offer for discussion the implementation of a meta-specific badge for a user who proposes a feature which is ultimately implemented.  With a certain lack of creativity, I propose the name 'Business Analyst.'  A nuance could be that you need to receive *n* 'status-completed' tags before earning the badge.

In the spirit of the Japanese adage 花より団子 ('hana yori dango' or 'f**k the flowers, give me dumplings'), instead of a badge, a rep bonus could be awarded per 'status-completed'-tagged post.

Your thoughts?

Comment: Mmm... dumplings...

Comment: i appreciate the downvotes, but as we are on meta, a comment would be appreciated

Comment: @akf: Why? Downvotes on MSO are anonymous just like anywhere else.

Comment: @Rich B: well, yes they are, but isn't there a consensus to encourage comments for downvotes?

Comment: @akf: And the site does that, you don't need to repeat the effort. It is an encouraged behavior, not required.

Comment: Comments for down votes yes, on Meta, it's a different beast, appreciate that difference. It doesn't even prompt you to add a comment on here either.

Comment: @random: I agree that meta is different, it is *much* less desirable to leave a comment here IMO. That is all just noise.

Comment: @Rich B: would that imply that you should have just upvoted @random's comment, as it is the built-in convention to indicate agreement with a comment?  I mean, otherwise it is just noise.

Comment: @akf: To vote, you need votes left.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just an observation more than a vote for/against this.

With all the features added to Stack Overflow in the last year, can you think of any features that were a direct result of an idea by a *specific* person? Name the person and the feature. Maybe one? Most feature origins aren't that direct.

The point is that many features are borne out of on-going collaboration. Some are resurrected ideas whose time has finally come. Some are finally implemented only after repeated nagging and persistent feature requests. I have requested features which were already in the works.

The result is that Jeff&Co **would have to implement some formal feature-tracking process**. Then they have to resolve the inevitable me-first/me-too conflicts that would erupt every time they tweak some part of the system operation.

Are the net results worth it?

Comment: According to the blog, vote-to-close was pretty much a direct result of a request by Mike Stone. But, he made it via email, so that doesn't really make a good argument for a badge on Meta...

Comment: True - most 'feature-ideas' are independently thought of by multiple people. On my products I tend to add a feature when enough separate people have separately requested it. This is cheaper and more effective than combing a 'back-log' and (for the interested reader) more in-line with Lean thinking.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there has been any shortage of feature requests, so I don't know you would think there possibly needs to be any type of extra encouragement to do so.

I don't think a possible reward would be a bad idea. I like the badge idea to a point. Like I said, I just can't imagine it being something to encourage a behavior that is already very prevalent (perhaps some would argue too prevalent).

Comment: Yeah, I was going to put in an acknowledgment of a double-edged sword here, but I figured that it would come out in discussion (thus the tag).  The badge, in my mind, would be akin to the Good Answer badge - where the 100pt reward for 10 upvotes, as Rich B says, would be 'good enough' but the recognition for the good idea would be a token of gratitude.

Answer (score 2):

I don't agree that there should be a badge for this, as most feature requests are collaborative efforts.

Please note that I regularly browse **the list of feature requests by votes**, like so:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request+-status-declined+-status-deferred&sort=votes

So if you want a [feature-request] implemented, **vote for it** -- or convince others to vote for it!

Here's a list of feature requests that have been implemented to date.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=feature-request%20status-completed&sort=newest

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, about ... a decade and half after the original question (and a good many feature requests happening, and a good many not or deferred) - I feel like seeing something that you suggested or need is a reward enough.

The funny thing is I suspect not 'all' of them are a direct result of my feature request, and some of them might be very very delayed. I do *get* a bit of joy from seeing the results  of my [first question here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20954/have-an-option-to-watch-a-question-without-posting)  - which became follows and saves or other things I've wanted to see.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds horrible; the rep you get here on Meta should be more than enough.