# Wikipedia-like Special:Watchlist option

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, wikipedia

I am looking for a [Special:Watchlist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Watching_pages) option — like the one at Wikipedia — which would allow me to keep track of the changes made to a set of questions over several days.

I think there are duplicate requests for this, but I could not find them.

**Update**: Oh yeah, I know you can ask me to use RSS, but that's not similar to Wikipedia's watchlist.

**Update**: Noticed a change, now you get a banner with a summary of changes to your Favourites. They have implemented it, I guess. More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20954/have-an-option-to-watch-a-question-without-posting/51824#51824).

Answer (score 1):

> is it close to Wikipedia watchlist? Nahhh!!!

It could be. RSS is in the eye of the beholder (or reader). No one's making you put an particular RSS feed in the same reader as your general RSS feeds. If you want to see some aggregated content in a specific way, go find a reader or service that will do that for you for that feed.

Comment: But, if it is easy, why not have in SO itself? Sure, I can find something for my need, but again, you never felt a need for Wiki like watchlist? that's what puzzling me.

Comment: @Guru - because there are thousands of potential views or uses for a feed.  Creating one view of data is easy, but maintaining many is hard.  The same reasons you apply to why they should create a wiki:watchlist can also be applied to _many_ other requests as well.  So they provide the rss feed as a way that anyone can get the exact view (or nearly so) that they want.  If you want it as part of the site, you can even use greasemonkey to create your addon.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that's the way to go more or less. It was more of puzzling to see why this feature was not there. Lets see. :)