# Sunsets are often memorable - could we have a tag for deprecated features?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, meta

Inspired by [a comment here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves-temporarily-disabled#comment1275942_382019)  - while it isn't something *that* common, there's often posts about features we no longer have. While SO has more of these - [teams 1.0](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307513/the-power-of-teams-a-proposed-expansion-of-stack-overflow) came to mind,  [Jobs and Developer Stories](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415293/sunsetting-jobs-developer-story) is a prominent example, and [documentation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354217/sunsetting-documentation) is another example. More recently, we have the (ongoing) replacement of bookmarks by saves (and something along those lines was literally [the first feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20954/have-an-option-to-watch-a-question-without-posting) I made on then-MSO.)

We have a lot of history, some of it about historical *cul-de-sacs* and others of things that were.

It might be useful to denote questions about these features and subjects a little more formally, especially on MSE and MSO with a feature tag akin to the ones we have now [feature-retired](/questions/tagged/feature-retired), though as a mod-only red tag so folks who are not as familiar with SE's history will have some context.

Comment: Not to forget the mobile SE/SO apps

Comment: They still live on in my heart. And my other phone, but yes.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some features for this:

1. Closing the question. MSE and MSO both set aside close reasons for this. Other child metas typically don't have any custom close reasons, which means a mod could so choose to add one (or just close it with a custom reason).
2. Obsolete lock. ([Example](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11279/42375).) Like your suggestion, it can only be applied by those with mod privileges. It's a little more obvious than a tag because there's a big banner at the top. It locks the post and its answers which may or may not be desired.

   > **Obsolete**. This question is obsolete because the content is out of date. It is not currently accepting new answers or interactions.

Comment: One downside to this over specific tags is that this makes searching a bit harder: You can search for questions that are closed or locked, but not for questions that are closed/locked with a specific reason. A tag would allow for an easier way to find all of these retired features in one list (even when they can/should probably still be closed and locked).

Comment: @Tinkeringbell given the policy of not bumping posts on sites like MSE the tag wouldn't be of much use. If it's a *"mod only tag"* it would see even less use (realistically, there should over 10k posts to retag).

Comment: @bad_coder we bump posts when cleaning up tags, if the community agrees on it. If they can agree upon wanting a tag for retired features, the bumping similarly wouldn't be any problem. As for the mod-only.. Don't worry about that. There's mods here destroying spammers out of boredom, they can do retagging if needed too.

Comment: If anything, it seems like the community could create and maintain a single Q&A to use as a reference for listing deprecated features – then, it could link to the tags associated with those features. Beyond that, each significant feature (deprecated or otherwise) usually already has one or more tags on MSE used to group questions about it together... I don't see the benefit of an additional [meta tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) being used solely to indicate that the feature the question is about is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

One possible system procedure that's **closing** questions about deprecated/sunset features (or solved bug reports) as *"no longer reproducible"* isn't consensual on the metas (see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/372402)). Sometimes it's considered enough of a reason to close, sometimes not.

The main problem with closing -why I assume it's not popular with one section of the crowd- is that you're setting back counts towards the [socratic badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) for what were valid posts.

> a tag for deprecated features?

The main use of a tag is mostly for filtering searches, while there's merit to the idea it raises 2 main issues:

1. Wouldn't the retag edit be doomed to bump the post (unlike a closure)?
2. Wouldn't conceptually a closure still be the most appropriate action?

The above taken together leads me to believe the ideal solution would be a special tag that doesn't bump posts and still counts a positively scored but closed post towards question asking badge progression.

Comment: We can retag *as* we go along. And I'd say that this wouldn't be a 'replacement' for closures as no repro in most cases, just an additional thing

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I don't think the tag will solve the most substantial part of the problem (which you don't address). Including the bumps, or the tens of thousands of questions that need closing, or the fact that closures set back users on their badge pursuits. *"As we go along"* is usually an excuse to not curate anything from the backlog. The much harder issue is whether to close, or not (which you also don't address). Put into perspective the tag is the least relevant of all the parts.