# Why is my reputation for the StackOverflow trilogy sites not shown on all of the sites?

Tags: feature-request

Let's say one user has a lot of reputation on SO but almost none on another website such as Super User, wouldn't it make sense to display either:

- Something like an average of rep
  through all the websites
- The rep on each websites
- A badge-like image for each website meaning
  "more than 500rep, more than 1000
  rep" etc
- Something else

I think this would make sense because, for instance, reputation earned on Serverfault means that the person is knowledgeable about server-related things. So why not showcase that on Stackoverflow if this person asks/answer a question over there?

Also this might encourage people to post on all websites. I'm saying this because I'm mostly on SO, but I like the other initiatives. After a few month on SO I gained some rep and it feels painful to start all over again on another website, so I kind of not go over there a lot. I know this a silly way of thinking about rep and this is not the point of reputation but I'm sure I'm not the only one.

This is not vital, but I'd like to know you guys inputs about this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your knowledge of ipod-repair is almost irrelevant on Stackoverflow. Two different contexts. If you want your rep on other sites, you can paste your flair into your profiles on other sites. But each so-site is exclusive and distinct, and there probably should be little or no overlap between the activity you have on them.

Comment: Posting the flair actually makes a lot of sense, I'm going to do that right now. I'm not saying to merge the different rep, just give a way to know how active a user is on the other websites. Of course this might not be the direction that people want to take if the idea is to avoid activity overlap

Comment: The person who needs their iPod fixed also doesn't care that you built a multimillion dollar banking application in Java with an IBM MQ middleware solution and know Spring like the back of your hand.

Comment: actually you can't paste your flair on SO, or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: You don't need to post your flair: anyone who cares can clikc on you "accounts" tab.

Comment: But who does that? It's awesome the way they are linked together and I really like that, but it's a bit hidden / requires clicks :)

Answer (score 5):

> Something like an average of rep through all the websites

I certainly don't want my low rep on MSO, SU, SF affecting my rep on SO.

Comment: What I was saying is it would not replace the SO rep, it would just be another indicator

Answer (score 2):

This is why we have the associate accounts feature. You can see what the user has gained on the sister sites.

Rep/Knowledge may blend a little in some areas, but does not transfer/translate into the other sites.

For example: I know programmers that could hardly troubleshoot a keyboard problem some days.

Comment: and I like that, but is this enough?

Comment: Yah, I think they did a great job with it. You can click on anyone's account and go straight to it and see what they have asked/answered on any site through the associated accounts tab.

Answer (score 1):

People can find this information if you have associated your accounts, but reputation is intentionally disparate between the sites, just because you know one area well does not mean you know anything about another. I did previously [suggest](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/3560#3560) adding a badge that would add an additional way that people on one site could see you are exceptional on another.

Comment: A badge would be cool

Comment: While cross-site rep-building isn't discouraged in any way I can tell, it's not something that's actively promoted - which is the purpose of the badge system (to reinforce desired behaviors).

Comment: @Kara, I agree it is not too strongly encouraged currently (though the rep reward for associating accounts does somewhat), but I think it would be a good behavior to encourage.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could be implemented it as a mouseover on the avatar.