# Badge for upvoting new users

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, badges, up-votes

I am a newcomer in a few stackexchange sites, and it's very frustating to be at reputation 1 and not being able to upvote anything.

Perhaps there could be a small incentive like awarding a badge for the first two upvotes to a user, or for upvoting users with less than 20 rep, or something like that

Comment: If your question is about stackexchange, this should be asked on http://meta.stackexchange.com/. If you meant SO, SU, and/or SF, it would be good to reword your question.

Comment: It applies to all stackoverflow powered sites

Comment: You might submit it under the Badge ideas question (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)

Comment: @JQAn: Is your proposal mean badge to new users or badge to voters?

Comment: Voters. "badge for the first two upvotes to a [new] user"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the SE sites, while in Beta should give out 100 rep to get things going.

Answer (score 12):

I think voting should be based strictly on the merit of the question/answer. Any incentive to vote for a lower quality post will only hurt the site.