# We need a Nepotism badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, negative-badges

I see a number of cases (won't mention names) where a person will answer a number of questions for the same person over and over to where I start to believe that someone is gaming the system.  Could you make a Nepotism badge if someone answers let's say 10 questions for a single person?  It would certainly not be a badge of honor, but it might discourage people from gaming the system for points.

Answer (score 10):

Then Jon Skeet would have a Nepotism badge for everyone who asked 10 questions about C#. I'm really not seeing the problem that you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 9):

**No**. Someone either games the system or he does not. If he does, we have [other means](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) to deal with that; if he doesn't, then any kind of badge with a negative connotation is not deserved.

Answer (score 8):

Badges are supposed to be there to promote **good** behaviour, not bad behaviour.

Comment: **Peer pressure** isn't that good :)

Comment: @Moayad: actually, it is: it rewards self-moderation, which is good. Helps keep the site clean...

Answer (score 2):

Add it to the list: [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)

Personaly, I don't think we need any more "bad behavior" badges, but that is IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

> Could you make a Nepotism badge if someone answers let's say 10 questions for a single person?

Ok, you start off alleging abuse/gaming of the system, and then switch to charges of nepotism. Which is it? One person gaming the system, or one person taking extra time to answer questions from a family member? Because unless they're *bad answers*, i don't see how the latter is a problem...