# badge proposal: 'density'

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, badge-request

Calculate the score of a question or answer divided by the length in characters. Set up the usual three badges for achieving some thresholds.

Comment: brevity in all things... even badges.

Comment: Add it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dunno, brevity is good and all, but I see a positive correlation overall between length and quality, myself.

Comment: NOTE: This answer represents the exception that proves the rule.

Comment: if you do say so yourself :-)

Comment: But that's the point. It's really hard to write a high-quality (and thus extensively upvoted) answer that is really concise. Thus the semi-serious suggestion to offer recognition.

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you're saying.  I just don't think we want to be pushing people towards shorter answers - I think that'll lead to fewer well-thought-out, thoughtful responses.  Plus, there's already an incentive to write short questions and answers - they'll get more reads/votes, and fewer tl;dr.

Answer (score 5):

Hence someone who can write the shortest code to achieve best output will almost be the first to get the badge(s)?

And someone who writes like a journalist to cover every aspect/angle of a question context with quality will be the last?

Comment: Jeff would get this badge too often for his one-liners.