# Catalyst badge: received comments from five different people on a single answer

Tags: feature-request, comments, badges, badge-request

Here's an idea for a new set of badges:

- Conversation Starter (Bronze): 
  received comments from five different
  people (in total across all answers)
- Catalyst (Silver) :
  received comments from five different
  people on a single answer

both can be awarded only once.

**Update**: for both only count comments on answers, not on questions, because for questions there are usually lot of "did you mean?" comments.

**Another Update**: it seems that people are worried that most comments would be just pointing out how wrong the answer is. That is a sad (but maybe appropriate) view. I think it can be amended by only counting comments on answers with no downvotes.

Comment: @Another update, that is your second "patch" for your suggestion... whatever happened to KISS?

Comment: Add it here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas

Comment: Even if this were a good idea (I'm against it, BTW) you set the bar *way* too low.

Comment: Can precious metals act as a catalyst?

Answer (score 7):

In order to receive comments, there must be something wrong or not clear in your post... why would this be encouraged?

Comment: Good point. Many comments are like that. But even though, if a wrong answer results in a long discussion, that often makes for an interesting read.

Comment: Also, there is a badge for leaving ten comments. Those may not be too valuable either...

Comment: But that badge is essentially for giving feedback on other people's questions - a useful community activity.

Comment: I suppose to eliminate comments that just point out a wrong answer, one could count only answers with no downvotes.

Comment: @Thilo - but some comments on downvoted answers are explanations as to why they were downvoted. *Those* types of comments should be encouraged.

Comment: @Graeme: those comments are encouraged by the existing "Commentator/Pundit" badges. These new badges are for receiving comments.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to bump this feature request, with minor modifications. I suggest the following:

1. A bronze badge for receiving 10 or more comments on a single question or answer.
2. A silver badge for receiving 25 or more comments on a single question or answer.
3. A gold badge for receiving 100 or more comments on a single question or answer.

In all cases, your own comments are not counted.

Call them what you will, but I think this would be a good feature.

To counter @Downvoter's post that comments should be discouraged: why have comments at all? They're not just for clarification, they're for communication that is outside the realm of, but still relevant to, the question/answer at hand. Perhaps this might encourage more "discussion" in comments, but I don't think that'd be a bad thing.