# Badge on Stack Overflow for asking your first question on another site?

Tags: feature-request, badges

How about after you ask your first question on Server Fault/Super User/Meta you get a bronze badge on Stack Overflow as well (and vice-versa)? This would bring the sites closer together, encourage people to associate their accounts, and just be plain fun. I agree that reputation should definitely be separate across all site, but a little badges thrown in for fun would be cool.

Something like "Supporter" badge on Stack Overflow for asking your first question on meta (although that badge name is already taken, so we'll have to think of something else..), or a "all-around-geek" badge for having asked a question on all of the sites?

Comment: You already get a 100 point rep bonus for associating your accounts - assuming you have enough rep (200?) on at least one of the linked accounts.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is needed because there are already so many badges given to beginners.  You get one for 10 comments, first downvote, first up vote, etc. You can get all of those in a very short time on the site. I don't think one more is going to add much to the sites.

Also, instead of making a new request, just add it to the master badge request list compiled here: [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)