# Badge suggestion: Overtime

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas)

This badge would be awarded for hitting the reputation cap on a Saturday.

I'm assuming it's more difficult on a Saturday than on a Sunday (because of timezone skew) but if Sunday is harder then make it Sunday instead.

Comment: my initial reaction to new badge suggestions is usually a downvote... but i like this one!

Comment: Or rep cap on normal day + status is online for more than 20? hours continuously within a day?

Comment: Or maybe it's easier to hit the rep cap on the weekend.  You do work during the week, right? :)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38301/badge-answering-machine-closed was closed as a dupe of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas ; so for fairness' sake, this question should be closed as well. +1 though, I like the idea.

Comment: Even if you have more time to spend on SO at the weekend, there are fewer questions to answer.  And even if you do find enough to answer, there are fewer users searching so you have a smaller audience.

Comment: Would this be sponsored by the "Coalition for getting outside and enjoying some fresh air during your time off"? In the latest podcast J&J&? discuss whether the trilogy is powered by those bored at work, would this mean those bored at home, too?

Comment: I would rather call it "Nerd" or "Asocial" ;) Although I must admit I've already hit the cap several times on a saturday.

Comment: @BalusC, congratulations.  My main concern was "I wonder if anybody has ever qualified for this one."  Did you do it by posting on the Saturday, or was it from upvotes on old answers?

Comment: @balpha, the problem with having all the badge ideas in one thread is that they then don't show up in the search that the SO team runs when they're looking at feature-requests to implement

Comment: Sunday is much harder than Saturday IMHO

Comment: @Lance Roberts: I agree, and I'm not a strong advocate of keeping them all in that one thread; we should just find a consistent way.

Comment: Just add this suggestion to the "main" question

Answer (score 7):

Weekends and evenings are typically dead times - if you think it's hard getting a good answer to a moderately difficult question during the middle of the weekday, forget about it in the evening or weekend!

Getting more involvement on evenings and weekends is a good cause, and I believe this badge may help to some degree.

Comment: Weekends are for resting

Answer (score 4):

I like this.

As Jeff has stated, badges are there to promote good behavior on the site, and I think this does that.