# Post additional badge ideas as single questions?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta

Based on this [comment thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38723/badge-suggestion-overtime), we should find a consistent way of handling new badge ideas. Recently, [badge: answering machine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38301/badge-answering-machine-closed) was closed as a dupe of [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas), while the Overtime suggestion seems to warrant its own thread (although it has now been closed as well).

I suggest posting serious badge suggestions (that have an actual chance of being implemented) as new questions, while keeping the fun, not so serious ones in [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas).

What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

I'm starting to think we need to add another trilogy site just to handle badge suggestions.

**"badges.meta.stackoverflow.com"** perhaps?

Comment: it'd be great.  suggestions could get tagged `[status-completed]`, `[status-unimplementable]`, `[status-no-way]`, `[status-not-just-no-but-hell-no]`, ...

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll end up where they all, serious or fun, get posted as single questions anyway.  The fun ones are often still serious requests for badges.  It's better, in my mind, to just catalog them in with the Additional Badge Ideas question and let the powers that be weed through that to pick out which they want.  Close the new ones as dupes with comments of "Please add this to..."

Answer (score 2):

We had to give up with retag-requests all in one post, I think we have to move on from doing badge requests that way also.  We should start creating badge request standalone questions, so each badge can be evaluated alone.

The **`feature-request`** and **`badges`** tags should be used, so The Dood and his team will see them in the [feature-request list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37844/interesting-stackoverflow-searches/37846#37846) that they generate.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that we need to have all questions/suggestion/comments regarding new badge ideas in one spot. Let the votes judge which ones have *an actual chance of being implemented*.

Comment: But those badge suggestions are not mutually exclusive, so it's not necessary to vote for the "best" one.  And thats what the SO engine's answer voting system is designed for.  Questions, by contrast, are either good or bad, nobody cares what the "best threads question" is.  We care what the "most annoying bug" is, but we still hope that they will *all* be fixed.

Comment: A thread that asks for badge recommendations gives the community a place to vote for the *best 'answers'*.

Comment: @Perpetual: users can vote for as many answers as they like, so there's no requirement to just pick one to vote for.

Answer (score 0):

I was the one who posted the [Overtime](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38723/badge-suggestion-overtime-closed) badge suggestion as a single question.  I was aware of the [Additional Badge Ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas) thread and the reason I did not post there was because it is too long already.

It would work well if the administrators occasionally weeded through it and deleted the ones that definitely weren't going to be implemented, or had already been implemented, to keep the size down, but at 4 pages it's hard to search for a specific suggestions and new ones will go unnoticed.

Or maybe there are just too many badge suggestions already, and new ones should not be posted at all?

Comment: this is a fair point, but honestly, if you're *aware* of that thread and you *still* want to make a badge suggestion, *shouldn't you take the time to wade through it before posting your suggestion*?  anytime i see that thread bumped to the front page i go in and change the sort to "newest" to see what's been added since last i looked.

Comment: I did read it and I'm fairly sure I did not duplicate anything that was already in there (the most similar was "weekend warrior")

Answer (score 0):

Another advantage of posting badge ideas as single questions is the the automatic "related questions" search that happens when you enter a new question.  It cannot (at present) automatically search other *answers* to the question you are answering, so it's easier to avoid inadvertent duplicates with single questions than with all suggestions in one thread.