# Badge for getting more than one accepted answer in a single day

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

Based on [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38729), I'm posting this as a new question.

> Badge for getting more than one accepted answer in a single day

Different levels could apply as usual, getting a gold badge for a lot (help defining the thresholds, I'm not very good at it, perhaps we could use the data dump to get good values) of accepted answers in a single day

Comment: I'd say the gold version could be called "Ph.D" and awarded multiple times to getting 10 accepted answers in a single day - which is in fact within 24 hours from the first to the last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the idea, but we'd have to be careful.  There were a lot of answers accepted in the week right after they first introduced the Accept Rate feature.  That could skew things quite a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Would you want this to be a badge earned just once, or multiple times?

Given the various benefits already associated with having an answer accepted (various badges becoming available for that answer, the 15 uncapped rep) I'm not sure whether anything extra is really required.

Comment: As it'd be a daily requirement, it would make sense for it to be awarded more than once. As for why, as all the rest, it encourages good quality answers; I'd argue "why wouldn't you want it, what would be the harm?"

Comment: @Downvoter: I think it would add even more discrepancy between "very regular" users and more occasional ones. I'm not sure that's a good thing. To put it another way: do you *really* want to give me a load more badges? Seriously, I would almost certainly be the main beneficiary of this...

Comment: Well I don't know, I didn't suggest it thinking who would get it, in fact, I don't think I would; I just thought it would encourage more answers and quality, aiming to get your answer accepted.

Answer (score 4):

It's been said [elsewhere](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/1256#1256) that there should be more recognition for those who are active in areas which get less attention from the community.  From that point of view these would be good to have - there are no badges for accepted answers *without* some reasonable degree of upvoting too.  Perhaps requiring three or more accepted answers would make the badges just that little bit shinier - a *[Turkey](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_origin_of_the_bowling_term_turkey)*.

I there's a concern about 'badge inflation' surely that could be addressed, perhaps by looking at the popularity of question tags, number of question views, or limiting to accepted answers that don't otherwise earn a 'Good Answer' badge.

Answer (score 0):

How about more than one answer accepted by other people?  I can get two of my answers accepted in one day; all I have to do is ask two obscure questions and answer them myself.

Comment: Well, that was implied...