# Should StackOverflow have a "Developer of the Week"?

Tags: discussion, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-leagues

I think it would be interesting to show some type of recognition on the main page for the "developer of the week", i.e. the developer who received the most votes (not reputation since there's a 200 per day cap) for a week. While no mortal man can possibly catch up with Jon Skeet's reputation; they may be able to top him over the period of a week.

Could make the game a bit more interesting.

Just thinking...

---

**Update (Aug 23 '11)**

*I can't believe this idea got picked up (https://stackoverflow.com/users) after everyone gave me crap for it :P Now there's a week, month, year and all-time reputation tab. The idea is the same just the location is different.*

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been suggested before - probably in the badge suggestions question - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas

Comment: Votes are too easy to collect. How about the most accepted answers?

Comment: On the other hand, if you like those kind of stats, you may also want to checkout the `Stats` tab of the tag in question. E.g. Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=java&sort=stats&pagesize=50

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?sort=stats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this sort of thing would be okay on the podcast or the blog, but not on the front page of the site.

Comment: Good suggestion - might be something to toss into the new format too as a regular segment.

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be a pretty uneven race. High rep users already have plenty of badges; adding a developer of the week distinction would just pile on the number of "awards".

I'm not sure it would be really helpful unless, maybe, it was for higher profile tags, say the first 20-30 (i.e. java developer of the week, python developer of the week). Just make it a list of developers of the week, no badges or anything like that.

Comment: You could check the velocity at which new users are gaining reputation and accepted answers. That would give the "little guys" plenty of spotlight. (officially advocating the feature-request)

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not exactly enthusiastic about plafayette's idea. The only way I see it working is if there are multiple developers of the week. Otherwise, it's one of the guys on the first page every week for the rest of eternity. C# and Java are popular tags, that's where the rep usually is.

Comment: `<devilsAdvocate>` You could check in a different tag, or set of tags each week. You don't necessary go for the highest-rep user, only somebody with sufficiently-high velocity. Week 1, C# - Get one of the top 10 high-velocity users. Week 2, jQuery - Get one of the top 10 high-velocity users, etc. `</devilsAdvocate>`

Comment: How many users are already at "terminal velocity" (i.e. hitting the rep cap every day)?  I'm not being facetious, I'm curious.

Comment: @Aaronaught I remember Jon Skeet once mentioning that he was away for a few days and he still managed to hit the rep cap while absent. As I said, pretty uneven race.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be for this if the basis for the "Developer of the Week" title wouldn't be just reputation, but, say, the fact that somebody has gone the "extra mile" (providing support in comments beyond the mere collection of reputation for a good answer) extraordinarily often, or provided a truly brilliant, unheard-of answer. Things like that would have to be picked (or nominated) manually by users in the different tags.

Otherwise, we'll just have even more of a rat-race of people trying to collect as much reputation as possible.

Comment: This feels a bit like the "favourite question of the week" feature of the podcasts. If there was a way to nominate (or a heuristic to automatically select) a short list of excellent questions or answers, those could be featured on the main page and on the blog.

Answer (score 0):

This is for reputation, not upvotes, but the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow) show this.