# temporal Anti-badges with negative side effects to discourage bad behaviour

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badge-request, negative-badges

The idea is to "award" **temporal** anti-badges for bad behaviour, which will be **removed** when some kind of penance has been done. [**edit** One could even include side effect which activate some constraints.] I'll post some examples as answers, feel free to add more.

**edit** Jeff replied

> [You never reward the wrong behavior. You ignore it. You only reward desired behaviors.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59317/revertible-anti-badges-to-discourage-bad-behaviour/59320#59320)

I think this may be fine for training a dog who actually should accept you as alpha male and desire your attention, however some people behave "wrong" not because they want attention but simply because a) they don't know better or b) they are indeed mischievous. While group a) should be easily correctable, group b) will take being ignored as sign that they are free to cause `<dramatization>` havoc `</dramatization>` as much as they desire. Certainly, they can get banned for that, but anti-badges would at least provide means to put someone on parole.

*Consider this suggestion as user-ban's little brother*

Comment: As others have said before, awarding badges (even the anti kind) is going to encourage bad behaviour, not discourage it.  Not for everyone addmittedly, but there will always be some who try and get the anti-badges.

Comment: @Grant Croton: yes, and reading @Vivi's [link](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/06/25/fashion/25love.html) makes a good point there. The anti-badge could of course be made invisible to the user himself and only visible for other registered users... But I guess that would not help much, either

Comment: -1: Already been suggested, already been rejected. Many. Times.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: you mean like [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48832/what-about-a-set-of-negative-badge-catagories)? I understand that a permanent "trophy" is a bad idea, that's why I suggested a *temporal* marker with negative effects to the "achiever"

Comment: If you're going to make this a spot for all ideas relating to negative badges, then it should be Community Wiki

Comment: @devinb: right you are, done. However I start to regret having linked this idea to [negative-badge] since it is no real badge I propose...

Comment: This is great, except what's the point of earning the award if it just goes away?

Answer (score 17):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/12/badges-positive-only/

> Badges exist to reward and encourage the kind of positive behavior we want in our community. But not everyone seems to understand that. It’s tempting to suggest “funny” badges which reward behaviors that, if you really sat down and thought it through, are actually negative.

Have you ever trained a dog? (not saying our users are dogs, but the principles are startlingly similar)

You never reward the wrong behavior. You ignore it. You only reward *desired* behaviors.

Comment: I rather thought of this as a **punishment**, maybe even removing e.g. downvoting permission temporarily. It's just like a limited ban... But no, I have no dog, nor a kid, so I won't assume I know better. But punishment seems better than a [badge that could be abused](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59162/statler-and-waldorf-badge-for-explaining-downvotes) (although basically I like that idea)

Comment: @tobias giving attention is a *reward* not a punishment

Comment: @Jeff: I bet you read this article: http://www.nytimes.com/2006/06/25/fashion/25love.html

Comment: @Vivi: Hey, that's {intersting|disturbing|cute}, thanks for this link. @Jeff alright, this sounds convincing. Although I'm not sure it can applied in general

Comment: Pavlov is rolling over in his grave. No pun intended :)

Comment: Did... did Jeff just call us all his bit[redacted for those who read Meta at work]es?

Comment: @vivi lol, I HAVE read that one before, and even mailed it to my wife back when I found it. Good stuff. :)

Comment: @Jeff I thought some more... Your point may be true for dogs and spouses, i.e. for those who love you and consider non-attention as a punishment. However, pushing your point of view to the extreme, criminals wouldn't need be put in prison but simply be ignored since not paying attention would make them stop sooner or later. Uhm. No. That's why users can be banned, right? But anti-badges would be kind of a smaller punishment, say, parole.

Comment: (clarification to my first comment, I like the idea of that badge, not of abusing it)

Comment: @Tobias:  Banning or suspending users is analogous to going to jail or prison.  The analogy to negative badges would be forcing somebody to wear some sort of stigma (like Hawthorne's Scarlet Letter) for a while, which is not part of modern jurisprudence.

Comment: @David Certainly it shouldn't be *that* prominent, maybe just as small a note on the user profile page as when somebody is banned. And I'd rather think of comparing this to some kind of social-work-instead-of-prison.

Answer (score 5):

**Advertiser**: More than 75% of answers being flagged as spam

As a side effect, linking in posts could be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

**Lazybone** >25% of the user's questions are closed as duplicates

possible side effect: a big fat reminder to use the search first

Comment: Considering that negative badges are a perennial rejected proposal at meta stack overflow, I think you would be a deserving candidate for it.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I did not propose negative badges that can be show-cased as troll-trophy, but rather a little brother to banning a user

Answer (score 2):

**Crusher of dreams** 75% of questions the user voted to close have (without edits of course) been reopened for good (i.e. are open and have no longer been voted to close by others or even got locked)

Possible side effect: reduce close votes, or limit to dupe-vote only

Comment: on the other hand, the name could be used for of the [status-declined] badge

Comment: What problem is caused by a few people whose opinion on closing questions is rather different from other people?

Comment: @David I didn't say this is necessarily a good idea, just *an* idea...

Answer (score 2):

**Linker** >75% of answers are only one or more links without at least a useful comment or quote

Possible side effect: no more linking, or only answers with more non-linked text than linked text allowed

Comment: What exactly will stop a mischievous user from posting only 74% of answers being just one or more links?

Comment: @Grace Note: downvotes I assume

Answer (score 0):

Possibly instead of anti-badges, instead what if bad behavior got a certain related badge *revoked*? Like if you earned citizen patrol or deputy, raising too many false alarm flags could revoke the previously earned badges, for example.

Answer (score -1):

**Indifferent**: More than 75% of downvotes unexplained (or at least upvoting one "-1 because ..." comment).

As a side effect, downvoting could be disabled or limited until the badge is revoked.

Comment: And don't forget to discourage my behaviour by unexplained downvotes ;7

Comment: I love the reliability of meta's irony :)