# Penalise Downvotes without Comment / Reward Downvotes with Comments

Tags: feature-request, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

I know that this issue has been raised a number of times in the past, with some improvements being made to reduce the negative impacts it has on discussion, but the problem persists, and I would like to suggest a further change.

I am aware that the need to preserve anonymity when voting is an important aspect of the design of the community, and that making comments mandatory on downvotes would negate that.

What I am suggesting is that downvotes, without comments, should cost the voter the same number of Rep Points as the owner of the Answer. So that, if I were to downvote another user's Answer, I would lose 2 Rep Pts as would they.

I know there is a small notification bubble which pops up suggesting the voter add a comment to explain the vote, but it seems that is not encouraging alot of users to do so. If the same bubble basically illustrated a reward for the voter in adding a comment "If you add a comment, explaining your vote, you will gain 1 Rep Pt." there may be a greater engagement for people to do so.

(*Yes, I am raising this as I have had 2 downvotes - and no other actions on my answers - in the last 48 hours with no comments, no explanations and no ideas why they did so. But I still think there is merit in this idea all the same.*)

Comment: Sorry, but it seems we're [tilting at windmills](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilting_at_windmills) here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59162/statler-and-waldorf-badge-for-explaining-downvotes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59317/revertible-anti-badges-to-discourage-bad-behaviour/59318#59318 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2263/require-comments-on-downvotes-closed ...

Comment: Does it not suggest that there is a problem (user-perceived or otherwise) in a system if that many people are offering suggested solutions to something which gives them difficulty or detracts from their experience? I note that one of the suggestions was enacted, but as I mentioned in this "Question", I do not believe that suggestion has served the purpose for which it was originally put forward. Closing off these questions in a knee-jerk reaction is like refusing to attend a fire alarm because "it was burning last week, but we put it out".

Comment: I have downvoted you, my answer *should* serve as my response. But your suggestion would force me to also add this additional comment to explicitly state that I was one of those who downvoted you. Note, I am not telling you anything that you could not get from my response.

Comment: The suggestion is a worthy idea, but the execution would cause many problems. This is why it has been rejected in all it's previous permutations.

Comment: Can you please express uour opinion on marking question as duplicate at the following link: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/219750/is-it-correct-to-mark-these-two-questions-as-a-duplicate

Answer (score 14):

The following links may be helpful to you:

### First: [A note on the psychology of downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21080/why-are-people-afraid-of-downvotes/21092#21092)

Key Quote:

> [Taking downvotes too seriously is an] erroneous assumption that they've *done something wrong*, rather than the truth [which is] that they've misunderstood the meaning of something *done to them*.

Downvotes should be taken as seriously as any "Caution: Falling Rocks" sign. It means you should keep your eyes peeled, but you don't stop driving, and you don't burst into tears.

### [Change Down Voting to Require Comment for Why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55380/change-down-voting-to-require-comment-for-why-change-flag-to-report/) <sub>(caution, very long)</sub>

Relevant points of my (very long) [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55380/change-down-voting-to-require-comment-for-why-change-flag-to-report/55435#55435)

> The negative reputation is rather minor, and the downvote **is** valid critisicm. It is not the most constructive criticism, but it is a very quick and easy way to indicate that "I find flaw with your answer".
>
> As for being helpful, if I'm lost in New York city and I ask someone for directions, it doesn't matter how nice they are, if they are wrong. I appreciate that they were trying to help, but if they didn't know the correct answer, they should probably have stayed silent.

Downvotes are to indicate that the answer is wrong. On a technical advice site, this is *critical*. It is not only to indicate to the answerer, but to *everyone else* that they should not follow the advice within. While that's a little harsh, it helps *a lot* of people very quickly. Explaining your downvote is often just asking for a fight, because the answerer will refuse to concede.

### [**If you don’t like my question you have to explain why.**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50738/if-you-dont-like-my-question-you-have-to-explain-why/)

Key point of my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50738/if-you-dont-like-my-question-you-have-to-explain-why/50740#50740)

> Voting and commenting are completely separate mechanisms that were designed for different purposes.

Voting is to bubble the best answers to the top. Commenting is to engage.

### [**So annoyed with no-comment, vindictive downvoting**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting)

Key points from [TheTXI's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting/22935#22935)

> - I wish people would stop taking everything personal and assume that all downvoting is a vindictive personal attack when 95% of the time it is not.
> - Not every downvote requires a comment. I should not have to explain myself every time I want to mark someone for being wrong.
> - If someone doesn't want to give you a reason for why they downvoted you, then you should examine your post and see what it may have wrong with it compared to other posts.

*Not everyone is right all the time!* This includes both the downvoter and yourself. If you are wrong, you should try to fix it, if they are wrong, well, you're still right, so be happy about it.

### [Statler and Waldorf badge for explaining downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59162/statler-and-waldorf-badge-for-explaining-downvotes)

Quotes from my [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59162/statler-and-waldorf-badge-for-explaining-downvotes/59576#59576)

> - **Relevant comments**: How do you determine relevance of the (*forced*) comments?
> - **Regexing the comments**: Would any comment at all be sufficient?
> - **Repetitive comments**: Rather than upvote another comment, people will post an identical one for themselves.
> - **Downvotes are comments (Redundant comments)**: Every time you downvote you are saying that you disagree. It IS your statement of criticism.

### [Allow users to leave an anonymous comment when voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/leaving-an-anonymous-comment-when-voting)

> **If** you are *nice enough* to leave a comment on a downvote to explain yourself, [...] [Ed: emphasis mine]

Commenting is optional. It is meant to be.

### [Proposal: Require anonymous comment with downvotes [closed]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/proposal-require-anonymous-comment-with-downvotes-closed)

Jon B's [response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31302/proposal-require-anonymous-comment-with-downvotes/31304#31304):

> First, I don't think I should be required to justify my decisions to the world. Second, you can't force someone to type a meaningful comment, even if you force them to type a comment.

Comment: I sincerely hope that this closes the issue.

Comment: "(caution, very long)" - **hypocrite** `:P`

Comment: Skimmed it...and I have decided that people bitch about downvotes a lot...

Comment: @Justin: I'm not a hypocrite. It **is** very long! As are my posts. I often cut my posts in half to *try* to make them readable. But my degree is in Philosophy; being long-winded is what we *do*.

Comment: @devinb: I understand the points you raise here, however I do disagree with a number of them. I would try and elaborate here, but as I am limited to a short response, I cannot do so. I would also like to point out that my suggestion did not involve making comments compulsory, but rather simply rewarding users who make the time to leave comments explaining the flaw in the offered answer. This tact has just as much merit as the rewarding of users who leave correct or upvoted answers. You also ignore the negative psychological aspects of being "marked wrong" without explanation which ...

Comment: ... discourages people from offering answers.

Comment: @Lucanos. I dealt with those in the full text of the "psychological aspects" section. You'll have to click through the link. If you read the "Statler and Waldorf" badge section in full, you'll see my response to incentivizing comments in *any* way. Please read those two, and then respond again. (I understand I'll get two downvotes out of this ;) btw) You can respond here, or directly on those responses if you want.

Comment: @Lucanos. Furthermore, in directly linking "add a comment" to "gain one rep point" you are very explicitly encouraging gibberish comments. You are also discouraging downvoting at all, and as I mentioned, downvoting is a critical part of the site.

Comment: @devinb: I did click the link and have read the "Statler and Waldorf" Question, but cannot find any material from yourself which answers the psychological aspects I raise. I think that there are sufficient safeguards in existence to identify, tag and eliminate spammy/gibberish comments (such as those you believe would be spawned by compulsory or incentives for comment). I _get_ that downvoting is a critical part of the site, but I am simply saying that encouraging people to educate mislead, misleading or just-plain-wrong Answerers would also be inline with the aims of SO (in my opinion).

Comment: @devinb: To better illustrate the need to encourage explained downvotes, imagine if your computer didn't have any error messages - instead, you made a mistake and it would just say "No." One could argue that the "No" is a sufficient amount of feedback - you made a mistake and it says so in a simple fashion. But aren't the more detailed error messages, pointing out what has failed and why, so much nicer? Sure, no-one likes to see them (as much as people do not like being downvoted), but in both cases, the message allows the error to be resolved. (PS: I did not downvote your answers.)

Comment: @devinb: NOTE: I corrected myself, and revisited the first-listed Answer, which I believe is the one you were referring to regarding psychological impacts. My mistake. I do think that the fact that SO uses reputation points to reward constructive behaviour, ranks uses based on their total, allows differing access based on "scores" does also mean that a negative score is seen as a devaluation of the contribution made my a community member. If not, then the counterpoint may need to be raised - why have negative points for downvotes at all (and just flag inapprop. answers as spam)?

Comment: @Lucanos [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21080/why-are-people-afraid-of-downvotes/21092#21092) is the link that deals with psychology. **Re: spammy comments.** If the comments are spammy or useless (by what criterion?) do I re-lose the reputation?. **Re, educating the misinformed** StackOverflow is about answering *questions* correctly. Only the *top* answer needs to be correct, because that is the answer that the community is *recommending*. Obviously, helping *everyone* is in line with SO, but your *solution* won't help that, your *purpose* is good though.

Comment: @Lucanos: **Re: so much nicer**. Yes, it is *nicer* to do that. But you can't *force* people to be nice. And **any** error message is better than *no* error message. For instance, if I push on a pull door, I faceplant (recieve downvote). Even if there is *no* indication, aside from the handle (incorrect fact in my "answer") the downvote is enough for me to *find the problem myself* and **fix it**. Not all feedback is equally helpful, but feedback is feed back.

Comment: @Lucanos: **Re: rep as incentive** downvotes are an incentive to *not* be wrong. You think that people don't *mean* to be wrong, but the fact is that a lot of people will post inaccurate information because they don't bother to look it up. This does not qualify as "spam" because it is on target and on topic. But it is also wrong. See the "New York Directions" part of my original response. **Re:downvotes devalue contribution** This is their purpose. When you downvote someone, you are saying that they have (in some *minor* way) detracted from the site.

Comment: @devinb: I found the link regarding psychology (see my comment starting "NOTE: I corrected myself..."). *Re: Spammy Comments.* I think that the examples used repeatedly in discussions against the encouraged commenting are widely accepted examples of what would be considered spammy". ie "jsgqdgds", "(-1) you suck", etc. I am not aware of the current handling of spammy comment - I have just seen the flagging option when reviewing comments.

Comment: *Re: educating the misinformed.* I understand that the objective is to answer the OP's Question with the topvoted Answer. To educate myself on why my answer is incorrect, I could always post it as another Question and ask people whether there is a flaw with it, but the chances of catching the same SOer who downvoted is slim. Better to try and capture the feedback at the time of voting, plus, I am sure that people questioning why something was seen as flawed by the Masked Downvoter in a new Question, whilst within the scope of SO, would also be seen as a cancer by alot of users.

Comment: *Re: so much nicer* I am not advocating people be **forced** to comment, simply that they be **rewarded** for doing so. That is how you improve a community - reward people who are doing *nicer* things. *Re: rep as incentive* Agreed, an Answerer who does not research the material they refer to in their Answer should be voted down. That is one scenario, but there are many others where people are downvoted without such a clear-cut reason. *Re: downvotes devalue contribution* I understand the purpose here, I am simply mentioning that this is another reason SOers feed hurt when downvoted - not ...

Comment: ...just for the non-conformism you mentioned, but also because they see it as a devaluation of themselves as a community member. When that devaluation is anonymous, the effects are worse (which, again, you have mentioned before). *Re: rep as an incentive* Agreed. But do you not think that rep could also be an incentive to correct a downvoted Answerer?

Comment: @Lucanos: *re: spammy* Most unhelpful comments cannot be *algorithmically* classified as spam. It is a simple fact that anything that incentivizes comments will lead to half-assed content. Note, it doesn't matter if they are *forced* simply that they are *incentivized*. Both will cause users to generate weak content. *Re: devalue contribution* The misunderstanding and 'internalizing' (am **I** flawed?) of downvotes is the problem. If people don't understand what downvotes are for, they will take them personally. They simply shouldn't. Forcing (incentivizing) comments attacks a symptom.

Comment: @Lucanos: *Re: rewarding people for doing nice things* The problem with your solution can be summed up succinctly. Comments *after* downvoting **do not equal* helpful/useful/relevant/productive comments. I agree that we want to incentivize helpful comments, but that is why we have a badge for *upvoted* comments.

Comment: @devinb: *Re: Spammy* I am not expecting unhelpful comments to be algorithmically classified as spam - I am saying that users would easily be able to identify them and could flag them as such. Unhelpful Answers seem to be picked up pretty quickly in the same manner. Assuming that incentivized = half-assed would then mean that most content on SO would fall under the same banner. *Re: devalue contribution* Agreed that it is the internalization of the response, but when you are running a community which has a reward system, that is how people will view anything which is rewarded or penalised.

Comment: *Re: rewarding people for doing nice things* Whilst comments after downvoting may not be directly helpful to the Questioner (who, I know, if the priority), they would certainly be helpful for the Answerer, and may even be helpful for the Questioner should they read more than the top-voted answer (and I would not be surprised if they do). Knowing how _not_ to solve a problem, and why, is often as useful as knowing _how_ to solve a problem.