# How can I vote up everything on a StackOverflow Question?

Tags: discussion, answers, up-votes

One way would be to fire up Chrome, open the JavaScript Console and type `$(".vote-up-off").click()` and press enter.

Thoughts?

Comment: a down vote with no comment is worthy of such comments.

Comment: Please read [this link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59736/penalise-downvotes-without-comment-reward-downvotes-with-comments/59778#59778). It deals (pretty comprehensively, I hope) with why downvoters are not obligated to comment.

Comment: $(".OP").Downvote()

Comment: downvotes have a different meaning on Meta than they have on SO.

Comment: Have you tried usi... oh wait.

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether or not it is feasible, this (self-created) feature has **no** valid use cases.

You should not be upvoting (or downvoting) a post unless you have read the post. And it would take a fraction of a second to vote on the posts *as* you read through them. There is no reason to need to vote on them all at once.

Comment: Isn't there some underlying malicious capabilities of a little jQuery code and using some OpenID site integration? For instance couldn't someone create hundreds of accounts that are linkable to StackOverflow and simply crawl and downvote all over the site and take away people's precious points?

Comment: @hunter. Well, no, because those accounts would all need 100 reputation in order to be able to downvote.

Comment: Don't you get 100 points by linking to another StackExchange site?

Comment: I just started using this site and I have 115 points (would be 120 if someone didn't down vote this question)

Comment: You can only link your account if you have 200 rep on at least one site, and then you can only associate one account per site. 
So, assuming that each user only has 100 reputation (that they got from associating) they would be able to cast 1 downvote each unless they fall below the rep threshold.

Comment: I voted your comment up with `$(".comment-up-off").click()` but you're right, won't allow more, but it did show me a bunch of pretty pop ups at once.

Comment: Yes, as "FrustratedWithFormsDes" mentioned, there is a limit on how many comments you can upvote in succession. But you can vote on all posts at once if you want to.

Answer (score -2):

Except you can't because there are limits on how quickly you can vote (with cool-downs if you exceed it - or does that only apply to voting on comments?), and how many vots in a 24 hr period you can have, so eventually you'd have to wait for tomorrow to do the same thing.

Comment: That only applies to comments. You can vote on questions and answers as fast as you can; but you are limited to 30 votes a day

Comment: yeah, it works. If there's a 30 vote limit then I guess it couldn't get too malicious... unless you had n number of accounts.

Comment: `$(".vote-up-off,.comment-up-off").click()`