# Can the anti-serial-downvoting mechanism revoke the Suffrage badge?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting, voting-badges

If a user serially downvotes someone so much that they use up all of their votes for the day, earning the Suffrage badge, will the daily anti-serial-downvoting mechanism revoke the badge?

If it won't, I'm of the opinion that it should. Badges are for [positive behaviour only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59317/temporal-anti-badges-with-negative-side-effects-to-discourage-bad-behaviour), and they shouldn't be a reminder of past bad behaviour.

**Update**: The anti-serial downvoting has revoked the downvotes of the user in question, but he still has the Suffrage badge.

Comment: Generally badges are not revoked, but the count may be off such that if you receive 2nd one of the same badge, it'll just fix the number rather than issue another badge.  Not sure how it'd work with Suffrage, but good question!

Comment: @rchern: I don't think you can earn multiple suffrage badges.

Comment: I wasn't referring to Suffrage exactly, just speaking to what I know about other badges.

Comment: Clearly, we should have that user serially upvote someone today to cancel it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Badges are awarded monotonically - they go up, but they never go down without manual (moderator) intervention, [except for tag badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17854/398063).

Answer (score 6):

It may be revoked but its a manual process, however if we find that people are abusing the system their accounts may get suspended.

I would consider that kind of behavior abuse.