# Stack Exchange Achievement Suggestions

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges, fun, negative-badges

Maybe we could have some alternative achievements?

[image]
[image]
[image]

http://teamfortress2.fr/achievements.php?eng

Comment: I'd say, great idea with a minor adjustment. These achievments could be "poo achievements", which tear down your reputation and count as a negative bronze badge. Then I'm all pro.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48832/what-about-a-set-of-negative-badge-catagories (I'm out of close votes for the day, though)

Comment: There are already achievements...we call them "badges", "reputation" and "respect".

Comment: clearly I do not need to explain why this is declined

Answer (score 14):

The achievements in your screenshot would encourage poor answers.

If your answer is the same as somebody else's, you should upvote their answer instead of writing your own. The same holds true if a few other people already wrote similar answers. Upvote one or all of them instead.

The JQuery/Javascript achievement is more in a grey area, but in general it seems to me to encourage writing answers that would be a poor fit to the questions.