# Über-fanatic badge?

Tags: discussion, badge-request, yearling-badge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Please add an "Über-Fanatic" badge!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58404/please-add-an-uber-fanatic-badge)

(Disclaimer: I'm not trying to boast here, but to suggest a new badge)

So, I got the yearling badge on SO the other day.  Normally I'm happy to get badges (and I suppose I'm not *unhappy* about getting the yearling badge), but it seemed like a bit of a hollow victory to me.  Here's why:

I got my silver "Woot!" badge 30 days after joining, and my gold "Fanatic" badge 70 days later.  So when I finally got my yearling badge 265 days after getting my "Fanatic" badge, it seemed a little pointless.  Certainly this auspicious day of having been active on StackOverflow.com for 365 consecutive days should be recognized with something a bit more than a silver badge that anyone can get for (essentially) signing up and lurking for a year?

In other words:

Can we get a green level badge (or a super-duper gold badge or something) that's "visited the site every day for a year"?

And yes, I suggested this very thing [in another thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/26677#26677), but having come upon this milestone, I thought it might be worthwhile to bring it back up into the public's meta-eye.

Comment: If you're going to downvote this question (which I don't have a problem with), please have the courtesy to leave a comment and explain why.

Comment: @Dave: Downvotes have a different meaning here. It's just a vote of disagreement.

Comment: @Daniel yes, but *why* do people disagree?  Is it a bad idea? If so why? Or is to for some other reason?  In other words, I think this is a good idea (hence the question and the `discussion` tag), but I'm interested in knowing why people think it isn't.

Comment: One might have thought an "uber fanatic" would have known that.

Comment: @Neil known what? that downvotes are "disagreements" or that it's a bad idea?

Comment: You could call it `[● Stalker]` or maybe `[● Worryingly Obsessive]`...

Comment: @Alconja: [Script-Kid] would be more what would end up with: Having a bot hit the site for you evry single day.

Comment: I don't even dare of thinking about all the complaints "I missed this badge because the site wasn't accessible for me on day `<insert number between 200 and 365>`!"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If it were up to me, all those badges that can be earned by a computer would be removed from the system. I mean, opening the website stackoverflow.com for 100 consecutive days takes no skill whatsoever, yet it results in the same "reward" as an answer with 100+ up-votes.

Because of that, I don't like your idea.

Answer (score 5):

There [already](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/146/) are [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/145/) for attaining a certain level of fanaticism.

Do we want to encourage involvement in general, or involvement on every single day?  Extending the 100 days of Fanatic into 365 is too much of the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The badge description does not say you have to be *active for 365 consecutive days*, and it doesn't define *active*. So the reality is that you may qualify for the badge when all you do is visit once a week.

The requirement of 200 rep in one year is also quite reasonable - that is 40 upvotes on questions, or 20 upvotes on answers (or maybe just one bounty question). You could almost achieve that rep level by visiting once per month.

Comment: that's my point.  The yearling badge can be achieved with relatively passive involvement over the course of a year, whereas this badge would definitely require daily involvement.

Comment: @Dave or just logging on. Not really involvement.

Comment: afdasfdsa *(does this count as today's involvement? only 364 more days to go)*

Answer (score 1):

This would mean awarding a gold badge to everyone being smart enough to create a bot visting the site for her/him.

I think it's very well the way it is: You can achieve [fanatic] as the easiest gold badge - all the other golden ones require you to really contribute to the site.