# Please add an "Über-Fanatic" badge!

Tags: feature-request, badge-request, activity-badges, consecutive-days, visited-days

I have officially qualified for the mythical "Über-Fanatic badge", having remained faithful and dedicated to the site for 365 consecutive days.  Can we make this badge less mythical and more real?

[image: 365 consecutive days!]

Comment: This is all that I have to say: O_o

Comment: What about a "Being in need of professional help" badge?

Comment: Oh please no. I just got regular Fanatic about a week ago, and I can finally stop worrying that I'll forget a day. If this *is* implemented, it better involve a rainbow across the user page just like that

Comment: PS. This was originally suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas/26677#26677).

Comment: I don't think there are any gold badges that are identical to existing gold badges but with larger thresholds -- we'd need a whole new type of badge for the truly ridiculous

Comment: There are plenty of badges already, and enough badge levels as well. Trying to make a "super"-badge will just complicate the concept further.

Comment: Yeah, I think a *badge* is the wrong strategy here... Locking your profile and enrolling you in an OCD treatment program sounds like a better reward.

Comment: I think this should be rewarded with one-day banning for the recognition of such a contribution and making it the ultimate and unbeatable goal.

Comment: I don't want the badge implemented, but I'm giving +1 for freehand stars.  And freehand rainbows.

Comment: 424 days, 424 consecutive - I'm just sayin'...

Comment: @Marc: You are deep in trouble, my friend.

Comment: 9 year olds don't qualify. You have to be at least 10.

Comment: @Ether: Yay! Canadian! +1!!!

Comment: Sorry, Uber badges specifically require lederhosen.

Comment: +1 just because *finally* someone is getting the "Ü" right. Because, y'know, these two tiny dots they really make all the difference.

Comment: 952 consecutive days... Can I have my über-fanatic badge when I will reach 1000?

Comment: @MichaelMrozek, rainbow badges?

Comment: You're a maniac, in a good sense. I can't make it for 30 consecutive...

Comment: DOUBLE RAINBOW!

Comment: Just checking in here. As of today, I'm also officially a sad case with 365 consecutive. Hurray.

Comment: Only 365?  That just makes you normal.  (Yeah, my count is low at the moment, but twice it has been 700 on SO.  Trips to rustic parts of England are bad for continuity.)

Comment: If fanatic is gold, that should be? Ruby?

Comment: @Shog9 sorry I need my GL mod... he's at 1.2k consecutive  if I'm informed correctly..

Answer (score 70):

Here's your badge:

[image]

Comment: If that cat really were like that he would have capitalized "It's" and he would have used punctuation, too. This image is completely unrealistic. -1.

Answer (score 53):

No, **not** a Badge, the *Über Fanatic* should receive a popup:

[image: logoff]

> <sub>*I feel your pain ;P*</sub>

Answer (score 49):

I have you beat by 49 days, but somehow I'm not proud of that.  Rather than a new badge, perhaps we could have a **Hall of Shame**?

[image]

Comment: 424 consecutive days on SO for me...

Comment: @VonC - cool; me too. See you in counselling...

Comment: @Marc: If by "counselling" you mean "why on earth I hadn't visited SO on [Wednesday May, 27th 2009](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=25&m1=7&y1=2010&type=sub&ay=&am=&ad=424&aw=)?", then count me in. Because I know for a fact [I was active that day](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913059)...

Comment: @VonC - I think that is just as far back as that data goes. I too suspect I would be quite a bit more than that. The counselling was for behaviour therapy, in particular our shared compulsive and habit-forming tendencies ;p

Comment: @Marc: I knew what you actually meant by counselling ;) A more interesting trend though would be the number of consecutive days you visit *and* posted at least one answer (or question).

Comment: @VonC - I'm sure Waffles could find that for us...

Comment: Hooray for freehand rainbows! :D

Comment: My current run of 595 consecutive days on SO is going to end in a couple of days when I go on a cruise. Wonder if anyone else has me beat.

Comment: @gnostradamus: have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile ;)

Answer (score 37):

Congrats!

I would offer a special hidden badge for this, but unfortunately this is a fairly game-able badge since all you have to do is "visit". Doesn't apply to you guys, you're *legitimately* active users on those days, but our badge doesn't count that.

Let me think about how we measure activity and see if I can figure out a better way.

Comment: I think the term "consecutive" shouldn't be part of that new activity measure. Rather a percentage. For instance: more than 90% of the last 365 days, the user has done xxx on the site. If "xxx" is (again for instance) "has posted an answer or a question", that could become quite hard to game.

Comment: @VonC and it'd definitely have to be gold

Comment: you should help her, not encouraging her. She needs vacation! Ban her for her own good!

Comment: @Ladybug Killer: noooooooo!

Comment: Should probably just give them the April Fools unicorns full time

Comment: Nearly two years later, have you figured it out yet?

Comment: As for "too easy", "Fanatic" is often the second most common gold badge, but "Famous question" is 1-2 orders of magnitudes more common.

Answer (score 32):

This would be nice, but I'm afraid it's too easy to get.

Instead, I suggest that the Über-Fanatic badge on each Stack Exchange site be reserved for users that have been visiting the site every day since the first day of the private beta, and a minimum of 2000 days.

Maybe also require that the user hit the rep cap every day he visited the site, too.

Here's the badge in context:

[image: Badgy badger badges]

Comment: So you want me to be around for another four and a half years?  *Challenge accepted*.  Although I'd say that hitting the rep cap every single day of that 2,000+ would be along the lines of Deity or Wizard Savant.

Comment: +1 can someone use the stackexchange api to make this for real?

Comment: These are epic! I fell down laughing :-DDD

Comment: 2000+ (consecutive) days achieved: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309 (although I only hit the rep cap 1200 of those 2000 days)

Comment: If there was a "Made a Stack Overflow employee laugh hard" badge you would have won it right now.

Comment: I tried downvoting Jeff Atwood's answer, _but no badge_!  Bah.  Next, "Livid"...

Comment: You should have the Stack Overflow badge for earning Investor... (and of course Ponies! was a joke...)

Answer (score 16):

My proposal is to replace your gravatar with this for a whole week. :P

[image]

Comment: lmao[.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157377/133693)

Comment: @Sathya :D ahah I'm glad you appreciated. :D

Answer (score 15):

I totally agree, but I think it should be named the "Crippling Addiction" badge.

Comment: Not a fan of the name, haha.