# Anyone with a "visited: 5000 days, 5000 consecutive" in their profile?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, fun, consecutive-days

Back in **May, 27th 2009**, the Stack Overflow team introduced a little counter to monitor the consecutive days you visited the site.
And 30 days later (June 26th 2009), the [first "Enthusiast" badges were awarded](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/enthusiast-and-fanatic-badges/).

[Today, February, 3rd 2023](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=27&m1=5&y1=2009&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=5000&rec=), is **[five thousand days later](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=27&m1=5&y1=2009&d2=3&m2=2&y2=2023)**.

<del>[Today, 9th May 2020](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=27&m1=5&y1=2009&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=4000&rec=), is **four thousand days later**.</del>
<del>[Today, 13th August 2017](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=27&m1=5&y1=2009&type=add&ay=&am=&aw=&ad=3000&rec=), is **three thousand days later**.</del>
<del>[Today, 17th November 2014](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=27&m1=05&y1=2009&type=add&ay=&am=&ad=2000&aw=), is **two thousand days later**.</del>
<del>[Today, 21st February 2012](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?d1=27&m1=05&y1=2009&type=add&ay=&am=&ad=1000&aw=), is **one thousand days later**</del>.

So I was just wondering if there was anyone else with that little value on their profile:

[image: 5000 consecutive days]

Before:

[image: 1000, 2000, 3000 and 4000 consecutive days]

Because, for me, it was (and still is) worth every single day, as illustrated by the Oct. 2022 blog post "[**How to earn a million reputation on Stack Overflow: be of service to others**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2022/10/09/how-to-earn-a-million-reputation-on-stack-overflow-be-of-service-to-others/)", by **[Ryan Donovan](https://twitter.com/RThorDonovan)**.

Thank you (again), Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange team!

Comment: When you reach 10000, I expect SE to invite you and make a podcast as they did with Jon Skeet's 1M rep. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard well... that would be in Sunday, 12 October 2036. Stack Overflow will be 28 years old. And I would be 65 years old! I'll get to 10000 at my retirement party!

Comment: That must require a lot of vigilance (or a script). And a mobile device(?).

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum No, I simply [post at least one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc?tab=answers). Every day.

Comment: "At least one answer" really is no joke haha. And here others like me found the 30 days streak hard.

Comment: 5000 days = 13 years, 8 months, and 12 days. Wow!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Ah, **finally** we can take a day off!

[image: 1000 days, 1000 consecutive]

---

As promised:

[image: 1337]

---

And I made it to 2000.

[image: 2000 days, 2000 consecutive]

---

What the heck, since I have a picture with my fancy hat and tie, I might as well keep posting these.  Happy birthday to BoltClock!

[image: 2048 consecutive days]

3000! If it were baseball, that would surely get us into the Hall of Fame. ;)

[image: 3000 consecutive days]

Comment: Imagine your life as 33 yo without stackoverflow...scary!

Comment: Nope, you have [24 more to go](https://xkcd.com/1000).

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: darn it, I made my post 24 days too soon. I will update the picture in my question then. Next stop: 1337 consecutive days...

Comment: @VonC Another 337 days?  What the hell, that's less than a year.  Count me in!

Comment: @BilltheLizard almost forgot, but 1337 consecutive days was yesterday. Are you still there?

Comment: @VonC Yeah, I remembered to get a screen shot too.  I wonder if the other 3 made it.  :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard great, see you at 2048 (but... that would be 4th of January... 2015! A Sunday though)

Comment: @VonC: Dammit, that's my 23rd birthday.

Comment: I [believe this makes you a guru](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/18409560#18409560).... ;-) Is the streak still happening?

Comment: @rolfl Yes, definitely! Looks like we're due for an update soon.

Comment: Apparently you have not taken a day off, as the first line of your post implied you might.... ;-)

Comment: Hey Bill! Glad you made it this far. I have updated the "question". Still 48 days before the big 0x800! (http://numbermonk.com/hexadecimal/2048)

Comment: I feel a bit better about my 1530 consecutive days on Meta now. But only a little, since it's Meta.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Happy 23rd anniversary! (and Happy New Year)

Comment: Yeah, happy birthday @BoltClock'saUnicorn!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn A belated happy birthday!

Comment: And... that is now 3000 days! Still with me?

Comment: @VonC Yes, I'm still here. Thanks for reminding me. I wouldn't want to miss getting a screenshot of a big milestone. :)

Comment: You still there? :P

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος bad news: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-3333-days-3333-consecutive-in-his-her-profile#comment1013068_122976

Comment: @BilltheLizard, awesome! But what is about an actual days update?

Answer (score 18):

Regarding the question raised [in revision 10](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/122976/10):

**'Anyone with a “visited: 3333 days, 3333 consecutive” in their profile?'**

Indeed, [there is somebody](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/622/asaf-karagila) on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

[image: Screen-capture of profile of Asaf Karagila from Mathematics SE showing 3333 consecutively visited days]

(To avoid any concerns, I did get Asaf's authorization to post this here.)

Comment: Do you mean Asaf did not make it to 3652?

Comment: Not to jinx it but I'd say he did not *yet* make it.  [math.se] is a more recent site. The screen capture is from today. The streak is live (and I think pretty close to the theoretical maximal for [mathematics.se].)

Comment: OK, got it. I didn't get the capture was from today.

Comment: @VonC I am happy to confirm that some days ago he passed the "10 year" mark.

Comment: Great! Congrats to Asaf. Time does fly fast.

Comment: He passed 4k some days ago.

Comment: Impressive. Congrats again. I just updated the title here: 4444th consecutive day.

Comment: @VonC Asaf passed that but no visibly record for now.

Answer (score 7):

End of an era!  On English Language & Usage I had 3958 consecutive days until I somehow missed on Sunday.  The timezones got me.  I was on Saturday at 2pm my time (UTC-7) and then on Sunday at 9pm my time.  But that wasn't good enough for UTC+0.  What a bummer.

Comment: I will take a rest *a week on Sunday*, I hope to get my Fanatic badge on SO by then.