# Why visited number of days in profile page of other users is not shown in us?

Tags: discussion, support, profile-page, visited-days

The user's Profile shows only **member for** attribute of users. I have seen some users who have last visited in 2009. And still they are member for 3 years and 4 months.

So I thought the profile should have shown the number of visited days which interprets how active (or addicted) the user is.

So My Question is:

Why is the **visited number of days** in the profile page of other users is not shown to other users?

Comment: It is a bit of Personalized Information, you can not see the login email too :P

Comment: How can visited number of days is personalised information. And consecutive visited days is not. We are giving badges for it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's private info. Would *you* like it if everyone knew exactly what you did when? Yes, one can scrape it via the posts list, but a one-click way to get access to this is excessive. And unnecessary.

> So I thought we would have shown number of visited days which interprets how user is active or addicted on network. That's why I wanted to discuss.

It's nobody's business how addicted a user is. To see how active s/he is, check their "activity" tab. Rep tells you long-term activity, the activity tab/rep graph shows short-term activity. I think that's enough for anyone.

We are NOT Facebook. Please don't make us Facebook.

Comment: How can visited number of days is private information. And consecutive visited days is not. We are giving badges for it. Aren't we?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk: Consecutive days visited _is_ private. Check it out on my profile. And, just 'cos you're getting a badge for it doesn't mean that everyone should know how close you are for a badge..

Comment: @SomnathMuluk I confirm "consecutive visited days" is private. The screenshot you see at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile was one I took from *my* profile page (I actually photoshop'ed it and removed the email field)

Comment: @von - you just want to show off your 1000 of 1000 days, don't you? :P

Comment: @Lix: yup, that was the idea ;)

Comment: Well, @Somnath has a point in that is not *entirely* private: you get a badge for exceeding a certain threshold, after which time everyone will know you have at least x consecutive days. However, you could argue that is easy to circumvent: if you don't want people to know, just don't visit SO for a day so you don't get a badge. (If you can ;)

Comment: @Pekka: That's just like how many other badges display private data. It's not really tangible. I'm against displaying the _whole_ data.

Comment: @Tim so am I. Just saying - he *kinda* has a point. A small one.

Comment: [plz no moar Facebook!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/WQhw7.jpg)