# Record for most consecutive days visited?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, data-explorer, api, consecutive-days

Is there a way to find out the actual number for the highest ever consecutive days visited?

I **don't** want to know who the user is that holds the record (I would hope that information would be kept private anyway), just what the record currently *is*.

If this is something that would require a developer to dig through log files then I don't want to waste your time, but if it would be a trivial task for a moderator to find out then I would be very grateful if you could fulfill my curiosity!

Comment: Although, I wouldn't be surprised if it's John Skeet with `DaysSinceStackOverflowInception - 1`.

Comment: and how this is going to useful ?

Comment: Not really useful, but I agree chown, it would be cool to see. I'd also like to see the "Go Outside" badge awarded for 1000 consecutive days.

Comment: @chown: I believe Jon Skeet made a question here on meta when he reached 1000 consecutive days. However, the consecutive day information is only tracked from the day those badges were created, not from the day Stack Overflow was started. So the "record" may not be accurate.

Comment: @animuson I think this is the question you're talking about: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile?rq=1.  Thats pretty crazy that someone has 1000+!

Comment: @Lucifer Not *useful* at all, it's just discussion.  I was curious so I figured I would ask.

Comment: @NSPostWhenIdle +1 for the thought (Go Outside) ;)

Comment: I imagine it's not hard to have 1000+ days if SE is your job.

Comment: @Conner We do *sometimes* take vacations. Some of them are even offline. :)

Comment: But what if someone is [_wrong_](http://xkcd.com/386/)!

Comment: Related: [Anyone with a "visited: 1000 days, 1000 consecutive" in his/her profile?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile). Specifically, as of [half a year ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122976/anyone-with-a-visited-1000-days-1000-consecutive-in-his-her-profile#comment327342_122976), there were only five users who could claim that. Jon Skeet wasn't one of them; if I remember correctly, he missed a day due to having his computer stolen.

Comment: *Sigh!* Now I feel bad again for missing one day during christmas. 763 days to go...

Answer (score 4):

SEDE doesn't give the consecutive days on a user, so no luck there.

We can do an educated guess though: the user with the highest number of consecutive days is probably a very active user, so what if we just check how many consecutive days a post was created?

[This is how far I got using SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/649484/consecutive-days-created-a-post):

```
select OwnerUserId [User Link]
,      CreationDate
,      days_between_posts
,      RW=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY GRP  ORDER BY OwnerUserId, CreationDate)
from   ( select OwnerUserId
         ,      CreationDate
         ,      datediff(d, lag(CreationDate) over (order by OwnerUserId, CreationDate), CreationDate) days_between_posts
         ,      DATEDIFF(d, '1900-01-01' , CreationDate)- ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by OwnerUserId ORDER BY CreationDate ) AS GRP
         from   ( select OwnerUserId
                  ,      cast(CreationDate as date) CreationDate
                  from   Posts p
                  where  OwnerUserId > 1
                  group
                  by    OwnerUserId
                  ,     cast(CreationDate as date)
                ) p
         group
         by     OwnerUserId
         ,      CreationDate
       ) cd
where  1=1
order
by     OwnerUserId
,      CreationDate
```

I had problems grouping the data together on the user, not sure why the results got invalid... Still working on it. Since we only get 50.000 rows now, we can't say who won...

On Stack Overflow, [VonC seems to do a good job](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/245360), but no status update since 2015.

Comment: "no status update since 2005?" But I last edited https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122976/6309 in 2015 ;) And today, I am at 2862 consecutive days.

Comment: Lol, can you image in '05 there wasn't SO yet? @VonC

Comment: Note: those are consecutive visit days, but that does not mean I have posted on *every* day though...

Comment: Agreed. The query is just the best guess answer based on the number of answers. Nothing in SEDE that could help here with the real consecutive day count.

Comment: I just tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/20405902/6309 on https://online-sql-editor.com/stack-exchange/com/stable/Sql... but `WITH` is not recognized.

Comment: No OSR has its own syntax. It is actually a SQL engine in front of the SE API (and many more XML/REST/JSON APIs). It doesn't support CTEs. @VonC

Comment: OK, that looked too good to be true ;)

Comment: Yes. Supporting that would require to read the entire SE API and store that in SQL Server... Sounds like SEDE to me. OSR is much more fit for real-time queries with small data sets (due to throttling on the side of SE)

Answer (score 2):

Current record on [Stackoverflow in Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) is 1766 days and it keeps going.

It's likely that following 36 results are top 36 for our site. These are results with 512 or more days for users in top 1044 by reputation for all time. Does NOT include days on Hashcode.

```
┌──────┬──────┬──────┬──────┬────────┬────────┐
│    i │  max │  cur │  pos │    rep │   id   │ name
├──────┼──────┼──────┼──────┼────────┼────────┤
│    1 │ 1766 │ 1766 │   11 │  59936 │ 178576 │ aleksandr barakin
│    2 │ 1233 │    9 │   43 │  23139 │ 176217 │ αλεχολυτ
│    3 │ 1184 │  275 │      │        │        │ 
│    4 │ 1158 │ 1158 │  119 │  10327 │ 178213 │ andreymal
│    5 │ 1156 │ 1156 │   73 │  15623 │ 217579 │ 0xdb
│    6 │ 1151 │ 1151 │      │        │        │ 
│    7 │ 1123 │ 1123 │      │        │        │ 
│    8 │ 1050 │  585 │    9 │  63036 │  17609 │ ЮрийСПб
│    9 │ 1038 │   78 │      │        │        │ 
│   10 │ 1012 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   11 │  977 │  977 │      │        │        │ 
│   12 │  940 │  940 │      │        │        │ 
│   13 │  898 │    2 │      │        │        │ 
│   14 │  875 │  171 │      │        │        │ 
│   15 │  874 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│   16 │  864 │  864 │   50 │  21518 │ 179763 │ tym32167
│   17 │  841 │   55 │    4 │  91359 │ 178988 │ Qwertiy
│   18 │  800 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   19 │  782 │  330 │      │        │        │ 
│   20 │  766 │  766 │  107 │  11053 │ 282277 │ Эникейщик
│   21 │  750 │   25 │      │        │        │ 
│   22 │  737 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   23 │  711 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   24 │  695 │    3 │      │        │        │ 
│   25 │  678 │  678 │      │        │        │ 
│   26 │  663 │    0 │      │        │        │ 
│   27 │  651 │    1 │      │        │        │ 
│   28 │  649 │   27 │      │        │        │ 
│   29 │  615 │    5 │      │        │        │ 
│   30 │  610 │  610 │      │        │        │ 
│   31 │  583 │  122 │      │        │        │ 
│   32 │  570 │  570 │      │        │        │ 
│   33 │  563 │   49 │      │        │        │ 
│   34 │  541 │   63 │      │        │        │ 
│   35 │  529 │   40 │      │        │        │ 
│   36 │  518 │  518 │      │        │        │ 
└──────┴──────┴──────┴──────┴────────┴────────┘
```

More information [here](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10139/178988).

PS: Data is actual on 3-Mar-2020.